# string as object reference to object variable

Tags: javascript

`var string = 'object.data.path';`

That's a string that resembles a path to variable.

How can I return the corresponding variable from that string?

Something like transforming the string into `return object.data.path;`

The thing behind this is that the string could be much longer (deeper), like:

`var string = 'object.data.path.original.result';`

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Comment: HTML5 data attribute name, dashes replaced with dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function GetPropertyByString(stringRepresentation) {
    var properties = stringRepresentation.split("."),
        myTempObject = window[properties[0]];
    for (var i = 1, length = properties.length; i<length; i++) {
    myTempObject = myTempObject[properties[i]];
    }

    return myTempObject;
}


alert(GetPropertyByString("object.data.path"));
```

this assumes that your first level object (in this case called `object` is global though. 
Alternatively, although not recommended, you could use the `eval` function.

Comment: Thanks! Already made a similar function, but asked in hope that there's a different way except loops..

Comment: For each iteration, you should check if `myTempObject` is still an object, and only then retrieve its property...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to just use `eval` you could try something like this:

```
function stringToObjRef(str) {
   var keys = str.split('.'),
       obj = window;
   for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (keys[i] in obj)
         obj = obj[keys[i]];
      else
         return;
   }

   return obj;
}

console.log(stringToObjRef('object.data.path.original.result'));
```

Uses a for loop to go one level down at a time, returning undefined if a particular key in the chain is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, award given to Chips_100 due to lower reputation. A bonus tho' for undefined return.

Comment: Thanks. (Must've been that extra time I spent thinking about the undefined test that let Chips_100 answer before me.) Regarding your comment to Chips about looking for a way to do it without loops, you can do it with function recursion...

Comment: Function recursion is still a loop, just, not a "documented" one.

Comment: Yeah, I know. And for this purpose I think a standard for loop is simpler. Some more reading that I just found from the related list on the right (includes an answer using `reduce`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference