# Get JSON property from fully qualified string

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have a JSON object like this:

```
var a = {
  "b" : {
    "c" : 1
  }
}
```

is there a quick way to get at c when I know the string "b.c" ?

I guess I could split the string by dots then drill down into c from that but I was hoping there was a quick way to do this in one go.

like I was hoping maybe `var c = a["b.c"]` but that doesnt work

Comment: My god... it's asked every day...

Comment: Javascript object != JSON. Which one do you have?

Comment: @dystroy This question is not about parsing JSON.

Comment: @JanDvorak Look at the link I give, it links to many answers for getting a deep property from a path.

Comment: For example it links to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference

Comment: @dystroy: this question is not a duplicate of #14396647. It may require an answer that mentions `eval`, but it's absolutely not the same question.

Comment: @dystroy: but #10934664, now you're talking.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I preferred the first link I gave because Bergi made an answer linking to 6 or 7 duplicates of this daily question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this, as you suggested using a split:

```
var a = {
  "b" : {
    "c" : 1
  }
}

var n = "b.c".split(".");
var x = a;
for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
   x = x[n[i]];
}
//x should now equal a.b.c
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qg7rD/)

---

In the event that the path is not valid, there is some extra checking that should be done. As my code stands above, `x` will be `undefined` if the final part of the path is invalid (e.g "b.d"). If any other part of the path is invalid (e.g. "d.c") then the javascript will error.

Here is a modified example that will end the loop at the first instance of `undefined`, this will leave `x` as `undefined` and will ensure the javascript can continue to execute (no error!)...

```
var n = "d.c".split(".");
var x = a;
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    x = x[n[i]];
    if (typeof(x) == "undefined") {
        break;
    }
}
```

[Here is an example of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/qg7rD/2/)

Comment: +1; doesn't require ES5

Comment: Note that it would be nice if you returned `undefined` if any part of the key is missing

Comment: @JanDvorak: It actually does return undefined, try changing "b.c" to "b.d". Although I appreciate it does not break the loop early at the first `undefined` that it finds. Ill have a play and edit ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Not with my edit it doesn't. Keep up!

Comment: Nice change. However, what about `a={zero:0}; n="zero.toString"`? :-) It _should_ return a function, but doesn't

Comment: @JanDvorak: How about now? better? I could also evaluate the function so that "zero.toString.length" returns `0`

Comment: I like it, better now :-)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend functions you encounter, but you can access their properties (as you already do)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {
  "b" : {
    "c" : 1
  }
}

var c = "b.c".split(".").reduce(function(obj, key) {
    return obj[key];
}, a);

alert(c)
```

See [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The link also show a how to implement shim for the browsers that doesn't support ES5. Notice that this code is simplified, assumes the keys are present in the objects.