# Filtering a object with query that contains reference to nested object

Tags: javascript, filtering, underscore.js, lodash

I need to write a filter function that will allow me to query by nested object, like this:

```
var data = [
             { twitter: { id: 1, name: "Bob" } },
             { twitter: { id: 2, name: "Jones" } }
           ],
    query = { 'twitter.id': 1 };

# Perform filter using data and query variables
var search = …

console.log(search);
> ["0"]
```

The filter should return an array of indexes that match the query.

I currently have this working without nested object support at http://jsbin.com/umeros/2/edit.

However, I would like to be able to query for nested objects, such as the `query` seen above.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572), you can choose a duplicate for free.

Comment: check this library http://jsonselect.org/#overview

Comment: That doesn't help @Bergi.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh: Why not? [Convert string in dot notation to get the object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference) is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Bergi It explains how to convert the string into dot notation but that doesn't help me write the filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function `ref` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10934946/1048572), your filter should look like this:

```
var search = _.filter(_.keys(data), function (key) {
    var obj = data[key];
    return _.every(query, function (val, queryKey) {
        return ref(obj, queryKey) === val;
    });
});
```

Comment: This will only work for one property in `query`: http://jsbin.com/uqabog/1/edit. Can you think of a solution that will work with multiple properties in `query`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now (sorry) but I seem to have got it working in ES5 (which is what I started with): http://jsbin.com/umeros/9/edit. Thanks.

Comment: [It does for multiple](http://jsbin.com/uqabog/3/edit). Only `every` expects you to return `true`, otherwise it breaks the loop since it already knows that *not every* item fulfils the condition.

Comment: Yeah, that's the ES5 variant. Only you tagged your question [tag:Underscore.js], so I used the cross-browser functions (and `_.every` works directly on objects as well)

Comment: What can I do to prevent it erroring when `data` contains an object that does not match the `query`? I.e. http://jsbin.com/umeros/11/edit

Comment: Use a function like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/1048572) that can handle the case of non-existing properties.