# How do I call a function stored in a variable that is of indeterminate depth

Tags: javascript, callback

I looked at this:

[Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)

But it doesn't answer my question.

This normally works:

```
window['class']['sub_class']['function_name'](data);
```

But now I'm trying to make a general function that can handle any depth:

```
function callbackFunction(callback, data){
    //callback = a.b.c, or a.b, or a
    callback = explode(callback);      

    //I need to be able to call callbackFunction and somehow callback and form their proper form below
    window[callback.a](data);
    //or
    window[callback.a][callback.b](data);
    //or
    window[callback.a][callback.b][callback.c](data);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `callback` is a string?

Comment: Yeah, callback is a string. Exploding it to find some solution is possible though.

Comment: Sure, but why not just passing an actual function? It can be pre-bound to the correct object with `bind`.

Comment: I am storing the callback (e.g. "a.b.c") as a string in a button's attribute:
<button callback="a.b.c">A Button</button>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string in dot notation to get the object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference) (and many others)

Comment: @lewicki: Why don't you just do `<button onclick="a.b.c(event)">A Button</button>`?

Comment: @Bergi: because it is part of a form. the callback function will parse all inputs and send it through with the callback

Comment: @Bergi Here the target is a function. If you don't fix the `this` binding, you might get unexpected results. So I believe this is half-duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the duplicate suggested by Bergi will only solve half of your problem. Since your final value will be a function, and since that function is a member of an object, you'll end up executing it in the wrong context (i.e., with the wrong `this` value).

I suggest you use something like this:

```
function getCallback(path) {
    var arr = path.split('.');
    var k;
    var fn = window;
    while(k = arr.shift()) {
        if(typeof fn[k] === "function") {
            fn = fn[k].bind(fn);
        } else {
            fn = fn[k]; 
        }
    }

    if(typeof fn === "function") return fn;
    return function(){};
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CEd5/

Compare the value of `this` in the callback with what you get by using the answers to [Convert string in dot notation to get the object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can chain references to objects/sub-objects/etc for however long you want. If you have a point-delimited string (e.g. `"document.blah.blah2.method"`), then you need to split it to individual tokens (e.g. `["document", "blah", "blah2", "method"]`).

Then it's simply a matter of looping through the chain:

```
var c = window;
for (var i = 0; i < chain.length - 1; i++) {
  c = c[chain[i]];
}
c[chain[chain.length-1]](some_arguments);
```

Comment: This creates a copy of window. This can't happen.

Comment: This creates a _reference_ to window. You don't copy objects by reassigning their references.

Comment: If i do: `window.a.b=1;var c = window; c.a.b=3;console.log(window.a.b) //prints 1`

Comment: @lewicki Wrong, it prints 3.

Comment: @lewicki: I'm not above posting some console output screenshots if it'll help a person understand how references work: http://i.imgur.com/HrzhFGH.png

Comment: 1 moment, i'll screenshot as well.