# Javascript - retrieve object property path

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = {};
obj.foo.bar = "I want this";
```

given the "path" `"foo.bar"` as a string, how do I retrieve `obj.foo.bar` (or `obj[foo][bar]`)?

Comment: `obj[foo][bar]` is this what you want?.So this will work for you

Comment: yes, I add that to the question

Comment: you retrieve the `bar` property the same way you initialized it and assigned a string value to it: `var myString = obj.foo.bar;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10934664/989121

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
function getKey(key, obj) {
  return key.split('.').reduce(function(a,b){
    return a && a[b];
  }, obj);
}

getKey('foo.bar', obj); //=> "I want this"
```

Comment: Nice idea! Just one thing: If one property in the "path" is undefined this will throw a TypeError. I suggest you improve this by changing `return a[b]` to `return a && a[b]`. This way in that situation getKey returns `undefined`, which feels better

Comment: @Tobo: Try it with a non-existent key, it should just return `undefined` as-is.

Comment: Oh I see if you input two in a row that are non-existent it will throw an error. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

if `path = "foo.bar"` then you may write

```
var keys = path.split('.');
console.log(obj[keys[0]][keys[1]]);
```

Answer (score -4):

just use the obj.foo.bar..that will work;

Comment: Thats not what he's asking. He's asking how to access the object property with the string "foo.bar".