# Verifying if a deep property exists in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I want to see if `response.objects[0].images[0].url` exists (and isn't null)

What would be the most proper way to verify if the url property exists in the object?

If I just did

```
if (response.objects[0].images[0].url !== undefined && response.objects[0].images[0].url !== null {
  console.log(response.objects[0].images[0].url);
}
```

But then it can lead to issues if any of the properties before the `url` one are themselves undefined or null.

Should I deeply nest and verify if each of the previous properties are either not null and not undefined as well?

Comment: if(x!=null) hits both undefined and null in one comparison...

Comment: If something before (nested not as far) as  what you are checking is null , doesn't that answer your question that the one you are checking is null?

Comment: put it in a try catch , if fails - you  know it or it's parent is null, or actually check each layer like this answer for same question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676223/check-if-object-member-exists-in-nested-object

Comment: @ScottSelby: If you detect a "same question", you should just [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as a duplicate

Comment: thanks   ,  will do next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a resolver:

```
function resolve(start) {
    return [].slice.call(arguments, 1).reduce(function(obj, prop) {
        return obj && obj[prop];
    }, start);
}


resolve(response, "objects", 0, "images", 0, "url");
```

if it returns undefined, then something along the way went bad...

Comment: How about: `[].reduce.call(arguments, function(obj, prop){`

Comment: @elclanrs: I feed 1 to the slice(), it's not just there "for tradition"... ;)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed, I do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891939/javascript-retrieve-object-property-path/18892019#18892019. There are probably other dups around.

Comment: @elclanrs: dots are nice too, unless the key has dots. an array works as well as arguments, and avoids any name conflicts with the handy and tempting string path. I like String(arr).split(/[.,]/) in controlled environments where i want flexibility like that...

Comment: @alex: slice always creates a new array, and it's generic, which means it works on array-like things like arguments and strings by using  _this_ as an array. slice's first argument is the left-side starting position, which we want to be 1 instead of 0 so that we have room for the object. putting it altogether, we call a generic method, [].slice, setting _this_ to arguments and the start pos to 1, which outputs an new array like _this_, chopped as specified before returning.