# Access property of object in a loop by array list - js

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I want to access the values of a nested object from a loop, and I have a stored array of properties comma separated.

Problem is my result looks like this,

```
["a,b"]
```

And im looking for this.

```
["a"]["b"]
```

Properties :

```
var props = ["a,b","f"];
```

JSON :

```
[
    { a: 
        { b: ''
          c: {
                d: '',
                e: ''
             }
        }
       f: ''
    }
]
```

For each :

```
props.forEach(function (prop, i) {

    var property = prop.split(",");
    console.log(property);

});
```

Comment: what you want exactly

Comment: Use a reducer, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891939/javascript-retrieve-object-property-path/18892019#18892019

Comment: ["a,b","f"].join(",").split(",") works well if the elements don't have commas.