# are all javascript object members created equal?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

for my website with jquery and jquery.ui loaded i tried the following experiment.

If in the chrome console i type...

```
jQuery.ui
>Object {version: "1.9.1", keyCode: Object, ie: false, ie6: false, plugin: Object…}
```

but if i ask for its type i get..

```
typeof this["jQuery.ui"]
>"undefined"
```

Could someone explain why this is? 
how would/should i tell if jQuery.ui exists?.... if the "jQuery.ui" name was contained within a string variable, how would i use that variable to check existance..e.g.

```
var myvar = "jQuery.ui";
typeof this[myvar];
```

Comment: You'd need to use `this["jQuery"]["ui"]` to get a property of a property. Just do `typeof jQuery.ui`. Why would you have that "name" as a string value?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891939/javascript-retrieve-object-property-path/18892019#18892019

Comment: So from this i gather, that using string quotes i can call a variable something involving a period, eg. Jquery.ui.  but if i actually want to refer to a property of a property i need to split it as Bergi says above.  As to why, i am writing a generic javascript loading routine and thought it would be fun to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `jQuery.ui` you are accessing the global variable `jQuery` and then asking that object for a property named `ui`.

`this["jQuery.ui"]` asks the global object for a property named `"jQuery.ui"`. Which is a totally different thing.

> how would/should i tell if jQuery.ui exists?

The easiest would be:

```
if (jQuery && jQuery.ui) {
  // jQuery.ui exists
}
```

> if the "jQuery.ui" name was contained within a string variable, how would i use that variable to check existance

Don't do this. Do not store the names of variables as strings. It's a bad idea. Especially if you are trying to inspect global variables.

Answer (score 1):

> if the "jQuery.ui" name was contained within a string variable, how would i use that variable to check existance

If you really want to accomplish this, try the following code:

```js
function existsOn(prop, obj){
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    for(var i=0; i < parts.length; i++){
        obj = obj[parts[i]];
        if(!obj){
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(obj){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
var str = "jQuery.ui";
alert("Exists: " + existsOn(str, window));
```