# Access properties in JavaScript in a safe way

Tags: javascript, object, properties, typeerror

Assume you're receiving JSON data from a legacy system which sends objects which may or may not have some properties which in turn may or may not be nested very deep in the object. I think everyone sooner or later faced this kind of problem:

```
> jsonResponse = JSON.parse('{"a": 1}')
Object {a: 1}

> jsonResponse.a
1

> jsonResponse.a.b
undefined

> jsonResponse.a.b.c
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

Now, what you usually do is to access properties in a safe way, I often access them as:

```
> jsonResponse.a && jsonResponse.a.b && jsonResponse.a.b.c
undefined

> ((jsonResponse.a||{}).b||{}).c
undefined
```

What I'm asking for is a compact, easy to read, fast to write, safe way to access deep properties when they exists and return `undefined` when they don't.

What would you suggest? Is there any way to build an object that returns `undefined` even for `(undefined).property` (I've read about `get` or `defineGetter` but they don't look flexible enough - and they're not supported on older browsers)?

Comment: You can use a reducer, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891939/javascript-retrieve-object-property-path/18892019#18892019, and MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @elclanrs reduce() belongs to Array. Also, the items in array are known in reduce(). But in Qualsiasi's case properties may/may not be there

Comment: `['a','b','c'].reduce(function(o,x){return o&&o[x]},obj)`

Comment: @elclanrs It's robust but I don't think it's compact nor easy to read, maybe enriching Object prototype with a getter based on this reducer might be a good choice. Anyway I was hoping some implementation that wouldn't require a major code rewrite.

Comment: Is there still no succinct easy to understand solution that does not require the reduce function? If not I will be writing an npm module for this. Looking for an easy solution in some of my own code too.