# Javascript: How to use an object's attribute if I have it like text

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, web, attributes

I have a path to an objects attribute in text, and I need to set some value on that path, but on the real object

Example:

```
    var path = 'object.children.child[0].id';
    var id = 1;
```

And I need to set it on the id on the attribute located on path

Comment: If it weren't for the `[0]` part, you could use the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference. You could convert `[0]` to `.0` and then us that solution.

Comment: I think `eval(path + ' = ' + id)` should work.

Comment: Thanks guys, you rock!!, I was actually using eval before asking, but just found out that since I was trying to assign text value, I was missing the quotes, it ended up like this

    eval(path + ' = "' + value + '"');

Comment: @SalvadorVillegas Nice you could solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval(), it interprets strings as Javascript code. People say it's unsecure, but it really depends on how you expose it.