# How does one parse an object with points (.) included in the keys to an multi leveled object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How does one parse an object with points (.) included in the keys to an multi leveled object?

Example:

```
{
    "data.firstName": "John",
    "data.lastName": "Doe",
    "data.email": "example@example.org"
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    data: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        email: "example@example.org"
    }
}
```

PS: You can find collections like this in MongoDB's find query, but I couldn't find how the do it, hence the question.

Comment: The first expression is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @Pointy how is it not?

Comment: @JimmyKnoot JavaScript arrays don't use `:` as delimiters between indices. That's object syntac

Comment: @JimmyKnoot run it in the console to know how it isn't

Comment: I see, it's already an object by making it associative, my bad. Edited.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Have you at least started with a loop?

Comment: This question has already been asked multiple times in multiple forms. Please search. You'll find things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var data = {
    "data.firstName": "John",
    "data.lastName": "Doe",
    "data.email": "example@example.org"
}

var result = {};  

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
  var value = data[key]; 
  var keyParent = key.split(".")[0]; 
  var keyChild = key.split(".")[1]; 

  if(!result[keyParent]){
    result[keyParent] = {};
  }

  result[keyParent][keyChild] = value;

});
```

And the result object would be like the results you are looking for.

Comment: For extra credit, extend your answer to handle multi-part paths. In any case, I doubt if your solution will work if there are keys with different first parts. In that case, your `inner` variable will be polluted with the previous entry.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @torazaburo , was only considering data that op posted.  fixed for keys with different first parts. have to think a minute about how to handle multi-part paths

Comment: You should check if the length of the split is 2 before executing the routine of the child key.