# Javascript - get object value using variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to get an object value by passing a variable to a function, but I'm not sure how to do this with a multi layer object. It looks like this:

```
var obj = {
  field1: { name: "first" },
  field2: { name: "second" }
};

var test = function(field){
  //sorting function using obj[field]
  //return results
};
```

With the above, the following works:

```
var result = test("field1");
```

This sorts using the object `{name: "first"}` but say I want to use just the `name` value. I can't do this:

```
var result = test("field1.name");
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `test("field1.name");` would mean `obj["field1.name"];`

Comment: `return obj[field] && obj[field].name;`

Comment: @Ramanlfc Yes I'm well aware of that. Hence why I said it doesn't work and am asking what is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string in dot notation to get the object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference)

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com yeh that looks promising! Thanks

Comment: Please show us how you are sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this?

```
var result = test("field1", "name");

var test = function(field, keyname){
  return obj[field][keyname];
};
```

Comment: Yes this will work, except what if the object had more layers and I wanted to use the function to target any layer of the object?

Comment: in this case you can write a function and work with "arguments" http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp javascript allowing you to pass N number on parameters to the function