# Javascript form serialization for JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, serialization

I am trying to serialize a form into a JSON object in such a way that i can send the data via AJAX. I'm using the function below:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
var arrayData, objectData;
arrayData = this.serializeArray();
objectData = {};
$.each(arrayData, function() {
    var value;
    if (this.value != null && this.value != '') {
        value = this.value;
    } else {
        value = null;
    }
    if (objectData[this.name] != null) {
        if (!objectData[this.name].push) {
            objectData[this.name] = [ objectData[this.name] ];
        }

        objectData[this.name].push(value);
    } else {
        objectData[this.name] = value;
    }
});
return objectData;
```

};

The problem is that my serialization does not take into account cyclic data structures. For example i have in my form

```
<form:input path="discipline.cnfpDisciplineCode" class="required" />
```

and this gets serialized as

```
{
    ...
    discipline.cnfpDisciplineCode : someValue
    ...
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to serialize the form to make it look like

```
{
    ...
    discipline : 
        {
            cnfpDisciplineCode : someValue
        }
    ...
}
```

Or do i have to implement the whole parsing algorithm myself?

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing built in; you'll have to do this yourself.

Comment: How does `<form:input path="discipline.cnfpDisciplineCode" class="required" />
` get rendered as HTML?

Comment: <input type="text" id="discipline.cnfpDisciplineCode" name="discipline.cnfpDisciplineCode"/>

Comment: @Chandu, it's [Spring framwork taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag). This will generate a `<input name='discipline.cnfpDisciplineCode' class='required' />` html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got what you trying to do, here´s is something I would use in this situation.

First, you can build a function to create an object and send it to the server using **jQuery.ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "servletAdress",
        type: "POST",
        accepts: "application/json",
        data: {obj: JSON.stringify(object) }, //it can be an array
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        }
});
```

Them you will receive the JSON as a String in the servlet addressed in the paramether 'obj'.

You may want to parse this in the servlet using [com.google.gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

*Or simply take the form and submit it to the servlet.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a ready-to-use function to transform paths like a.b.c into nested objects. Several solutions for the path-setting and -getting problem are presented in the following thread:

[Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

As you're already using Spring (at least it looks like you are, because of the tag-lib) you could automatically transform input-parameters into an object, if it's that what you wanna do.
The idea is that there is an object on the server-side that represents some state, you parse this object into a form as usual, and Spring handles back-transformation from input-parameters to the POJO by itself. Have a look at some examples for Springs @ModelAttribute annotation in this case.