# Most efficient way to reference nested object

Tags: javascript, object, reference

## My Query:

What is the most efficient way to reference nested JavaScript objects? I have found a couple so far, and am wondering which is the most efficient, and if there are any others which are better than those which I list here. The problem involves usage of a root object, similarly to that which many JavaScript frameworks use. **The root object is compulsory. Please do not post answers which do not use a root object.**

**Note that this is specifically intended for root/sub-root objects which have long names - referencing `a.b` would be useless, whilst referencing `abcdefghijklm.nopqrstuvwxyz` would be extremely useful.**

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify a couple of things:

- Via efficiency I mean firstly code length (which could in turn affect performance, but that is slightly less important). I am concerned about code length partially because of file size - yes, I would be minifying it afterwards - but also due to readability for anyone viewing my original code (including myself). Performance is also slightly important, I don't want long workarounds which would slow down execution.
- The referencing would be mostly for commonly used sub-objects, **NOT EVERY SINGLE ONE**. I state (in method 1) that many global variables would need to be created - due to the fact that I was assuming that all of the first-level sub-objects would be commonly used.

## Objects to be referenced:

The object `foo` contains the various sub-objects `bar`, `baz` and `qux`, each of which contain various other objects.

```
var foo = {

    bar: {

        bar: {},
        baz: {},
        qux: {}

    },
    baz: {

        bar: {},
        baz: {},
        qux: {}

    },
    qux: {

        bar: {},
        baz: {},
        qux: {}

    }

};
```

## Method 1 - Reference Variables:

The first method involves creating a variable for each of the sub-objects.

```
var bar = foo.bar;
var baz = foo.baz;
var qux = foo.quz;
```

`foo.bar.baz` could then be referenced simply via `bar.baz`, and `foo.qux.qux` via `qux.qux`.

Advantages:

- Reference variables can be very concise - a single character is the minimum possible length.

Disadvantages:

- If there are many sub-objects to be referenced, this would increase the global variable count. This is likely to cause conflicts, cross-script and otherwise - especially using single-character variable names.
- A new reference variable needs to be created for every nested object. Not only is this inconvenient, but it also requires the programmer to *remember* to create each variable after amending the object. Conversely, if a sub-object is removed and the programmer forgets to remove the reference variable also, then the code becomes messy with useless global variables cluttering it up.

## Method 2 - Reference Function:

The second method involves creating a function which returns a sub-object, depending on a couple of parameters.

```
function ref(a, b) {

    //Ensure that the first parameter is passed:
    if (!a) {

        return false;

    }

    return foo.a.b;

};
```

`foo.bar.baz` could then be referenced via `ref("bar", "baz")`, and `foo.qux,qux` via `ref("qux", "qux")`.

Advantages:

- Works for all first-level sub-objects, without repetitive and messy separate variable defining.

Disadvantages:

- Only really useful for shortening the root object - if the root object is named `a` then using the reference function would actually lengthen the code.

Comment: Perhaps a question for codereview rather than SO?

Comment: Please quit the foo/bar examples, they make quite no sense. Are you looking for a way to shortcut property names, and have, for instance, ‘myRect.aw‘ exactly refer to ‘myRect.actualWidth‘ (either when writing or reading) ?? I could explain how so if you wish.

Comment: I don't get the point... Is this about tree structures? What's the question again?

Comment: I think, like @cschuff, that you should clarify the question and example. I wonder if the solution you might found will have any clear advantage over just caching the right object when you'll use it several times locally. (var rect = myGraphObj.rectangle; var width=rect.width; ...). But in fact if your issue is mainly about typing long (sub)property names, the real solution is to use an editor that will autocomplete for you...

Comment: Please define "efficient". In terms of what? Performance? Code length?

Comment: @GameAlchemist, I was using the metasyntactic examples to generalise my question, thus making it applicable to more people who would search for it. SO SEO, if you like.

Comment: @cschuff, this is not about tree structures. It is about referencing commonly used sub-objects in order to shorten code using them.

Comment: @lexicore - code length is my most important factor, although performance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-a-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a graphic control object, that is an instance of a GraphicObject Class (function).
 Let's say one instance looks like :

```
grControl = {
   visual : {
     boundingBox : { x : , y : , width: , height : ... },
     ...
   },
   action : {
     ...
   }
};
```

The right way to create shortcuts is either :
• to cache locally the appropriate object in a var in a function that will use it :

```
function drawBBox (someGraphicControl) {
     var bbox = someGraphicControl.visual.boundingBox;
     // maybe you want also to cache sub-properties :
     var width = bbox.width;
     ...
}
```

• to define, on the prototype, a getter and/or a setter that will provide an access to the nested property :

```
// read-only example
Object.defineProperty(GraphicControl.prototype, 'width', 
                                { get : function() { 
                                           return this.visual.boundingBox.width }, 
                                  enumerable : true};


// read-write example
Object.defineProperty(GraphicControl.prototype, 'width', 
                                { get : function() { 
                                           return this.visual.boundingBox.width }, 
                                  set : function(val) {
                                           this.visual.boundingBox.width = val ; }, 
                                  },
                                  enumerable : true};
```

this way you can use :

```
 grObject.width
```

and exactly refer to :

```
 grObject.visual.boundingBox.width
```

Comment: I really like this answer - the read/write prototype has proved most useful.

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice in javascript depends upon the circumstances:

1)  **One-time access to that object in a particular function.**  If you're just making a one time access to a deeply nested reference, you just spell out the reference with all the intervening names:

`var data = foo.baz.quz.prop1;`

2)  **Multiple-accesses to a particular nested object.**  If there are multiple references to a particular deeply nested object, then you create a temporary local variable that points to the common object and then reference from that within the local function.

```
function getDeepData() {
    var obj = foo.baz.quz;
    var prop1 = obj.prop1;
    var prop2 = obj.prop2;
    var prop2 = obj.prop3;

    // code that uses prop1, prop2 and prop3 here

}
```

3) **Iterating properties who's names are not known in advance.**  Since you don't know the property names in advance, this is done by iterating one level at a time (sometimes recursively) and just keeping the parent object in a local variable.

---

If you find yourself making lots of deeply nested one-time references all over your code, then you probably want to revisit the structure of your code or data because that can usually be avoided.

Comment: Excellent answer here. You have listed everything that I need, and then some. I think that I would find circumstance 2 the most useful currently, but will probably come back to this at other points. Thank you!