# Convert a string to a template string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval, template-strings

Is it possible to create a template string as a usual string,

```
let a = "b:${b}";
```

and then convert it into a template string,

```
let b = 10;
console.log(a.template()); // b:10
```

without `eval`, `new Function` and other means of dynamic code generation?

Comment: did you find a way to achieve this? I might be needing to do it one day and am curious to know what you've arrived at.

Comment: @BryanRayner lets say your js program is trying to fetch a data from rest API,    whose url is  in a config.js file as a string  "/resources/<resource_id>/update/"  and you put "resource_id"  dynamically from your program.  
Unless you want to split that url into parts and save in different areas, you need some sort of string template processing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565794/how-would-you-turn-a-javascript-variable-into-a-template-literal

Comment: Instead of using eval better is use to regex Eval it's not recommended & highly discouraged, so please don't use it developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/…! let b = 10; let a="b:${b}"; let response = a.replace(/\${\w+}/ ,b); conssole.log(response);

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa I believe the goal here is specifically to be able to reference these variable values __without__ template preprocessing so that we can manipulate with them live rather than only on the server-side.

Comment: @KOLANICH to second Bryan's question, did you ever manage to figure this out? I need this for a project I am working on right now. I am currently using `new Function()` but would prefer not to in light of XSS concerns.

Comment: i have this problem too

Comment: Related: [Defer execution for ES6 Template Literals](/q/22607806/4642212).

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As your template string must get reference to the `b` variable dynamically (in runtime), so the answer is: **NO, it's impossible to do it without dynamic code generation.**

But, with `eval` it's pretty simple:

```
let tpl = eval('`'+a+'`');
```

Comment: eval is insecure, so is other means of dynamic code generation

Comment: @KOLANICH For particular that case - escape back quotes in the `a` string and it will be much less insecure: `let tpl = eval('\`'+a.replace(/\`/g,'\\\`')+'\`');`. I think more important is that `eval` prevent compiler to optimize your code. But I think it irrelevant to this question.

Comment: But template strings are not meant to be constructed by user, so the security of this method can be OK. But in any case I dislike it.

Comment: In fact, you can also run functions inside template strings.

Comment: @KOLANICH Yes. But when you wrote the question shouldn't you suggest that: `let a = "b:${sumFunc()}"; console.log(a.template());` will run `sumFunc` function when template string are created?

Comment: In fact I hadn't expected this behaviour when started the question.

Comment: @KOLANICH Sorry you dislike `eval`. However, remember that a template literal is itself a form of `eval`. Two examples: var test=`Result: ${alert('hello')}`;
var test=`Result: ${b=4}`;
Both will end up executing arbitrary code in the context of the script. If you want to allow arbitrary strings, you may as well as allow `eval`.

Comment: Be careful.  Since something like babel won't transpile this, this code will NOT work in IE

Comment: you can shortcut it a little if you add `` in the original string in advance : example `let string = '\`my is ${name}\`'`

Comment: Instead of using eval better is use to regex

Eval it's not recommended & highly discouraged, so please don't use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval! 

 let b = 10;
 let a="b:${b}";

let response = a.replace(/\${\w+}/ ,b);
conssole.log(response);

Comment: It is highly unsecure, be carefull:
_const templateJsInjection = '1` && (console.log("injected") || 1) && `1'_

Answer (score 169):

In my project I've created something like this with ES6:

```js
String.prototype.interpolate = function(params) {
  const names = Object.keys(params);
  const vals = Object.values(params);
  return new Function(...names, `return \`${this}\`;`)(...vals);
}

const template = 'Example text: ${text}';
const result = template.interpolate({
  text: 'Foo Boo'
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, Your solution works great, but when i used it in React Native(build mode), it throws an error: **Invalid character '`'**, though it works when i run in debug mode. Looks like, babel issue, any help?

Comment: @MohitPandey I was getting same error when I was running tests of this code under PhantomJS and it was passing under chrome. If that is the case, I think there is new beta version of PhantomJS on the way with better support for ES6, you can try to install it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work and i wrote down a regex for the same. Added as answer as well.

Comment: this solution only works if the back-tick "`" character is not present in the template string

Comment: When I try it I got [`ReferenceError: _ is not defined`](https://jsbin.com/xawutog/1/edit?js,console,output). Is it code not ES6 but `lodash` specific, or...?

Comment: @xpt thanks for your comment. There was lodash dependency indeed, I've removed it, check the update.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Mateusz!

Comment: It throws error 'SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.' when there is back slash in template.

Comment: @aleung, this solution is definitely not fully bulletproof, can be some edge cases where it's throwing exceptions. Maybe try double escape backslash. You can put there also some protection to escape critical chars, like backslash or back-tick

Comment: does not work if json replacer contains integer value

Comment: This is a _very_ interesting alternative to using `with (params) eval('\`'+str.replace(/\`/g,'\\\`')+'\`');`.

Comment: Great solution!  Note that this works with passing nested objects as the parameter as well!  Here's an example: given the nested object: `parent = {child: {a: "1", b: "2"}}
` and the string literal: `s = "${parent.child.a}${parent.child.b}${parent.child.a}${parent.child.b}"` then `s.interpolate(parent)` will return `"1212"`

Comment: If you got this error `Arg string terminates parameters early` check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59410199/6478359

Comment: This solution is far better than eval. eval should be banned.

Comment: This solution works great for me, but it looks a bit hacky. Is it safe to use it in prodaction?

Comment: Hmmm..... I try to do this: `var cloneHtml = clone.outerHTML.interpolate(viewerData);` and get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'interpolate' of undefined`. I've declared `String.prototype.interpolate` exactly as shown above....

Comment: Sorry guys, it works now: 
`document.querySelector("template").innerHTML.interpolate(viewerData);`

Comment: This is awesome, can you explain or your provide any reference to understand this ..... `return new Function(...names, \`return \`${this}\`;\`)(...vals);`

Comment: @mukuljainx Check how does 'new Function' is working: https://javascript.info/new-function. What above example is basically doing is this:
`(new Function('text', 'return \`Example text: ${text}\`;'))('Foo Boo');`

Comment: It's worth nothing that while this is an improvement over `eval()` because it doesn't leak your scope, the [`Function()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) _does_ share some security issues with `eval()`, as it is still evaluating the string as JavaScript, and should be treated with similar caution. MDN's documentation on [never use eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) goes into this in greater detail.

Comment: Yes, and to further support @cincodenada's comment, any browsers or webservers blocking XSS tend to block both, `eval()` and `new Function()`.

Comment: That should be best answer, but there are security reason for avoid `eval()` and `new Function()` specially in the browsers.

Comment: Please beware that changing `function(params)` to an arrow function `params =>` may break this for some reason, at least for my use case changing to arrow function broke it and it would always output `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: works with passing in functions too!

```function interpolate(input, params) {
  const names = Object.keys(params);
  const vals = Object.values(params);
  return new Function(...names, `return \`${input}\`;`)(...vals);
}

function something(t) {
  if (t)
    return "better than nothing" + t;
  return "nada";
}
const template = 'Example text: ${text} or ${r} or ${s("test")}';
const result = interpolate(template, {
  r: 'dog',
  text: 'Foo Boo',
  s: something
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 33):

No, there is not a way to do this without dynamic code generation.

However, I have created a function which will turn a regular string into a function which can be provided with a map of values, using template strings internally.

[Generate Template String Gist](https://gist.github.com/bryanerayner/68e1498d4b1b09a30ef6#file-generatetemplatestring-js)

```
/**
 * Produces a function which uses template strings to do simple interpolation from objects.
 * 
 * Usage:
 *    var makeMeKing = generateTemplateString('${name} is now the king of ${country}!');
 * 
 *    console.log(makeMeKing({ name: 'Bryan', country: 'Scotland'}));
 *    // Logs 'Bryan is now the king of Scotland!'
 */
var generateTemplateString = (function(){
    var cache = {};

    function generateTemplate(template){
        var fn = cache[template];

        if (!fn){
            // Replace ${expressions} (etc) with ${map.expressions}.

            var sanitized = template
                .replace(/\$\{([\s]*[^;\s\{]+[\s]*)\}/g, function(_, match){
                    return `\$\{map.${match.trim()}\}`;
                    })
                // Afterwards, replace anything that's not ${map.expressions}' (etc) with a blank string.
                .replace(/(\$\{(?!map\.)[^}]+\})/g, '');

            fn = Function('map', `return \`${sanitized}\``);
        }

        return fn;
    }

    return generateTemplate;
})();
```

Usage:

```
var kingMaker = generateTemplateString('${name} is king!');

console.log(kingMaker({name: 'Bryan'}));
// Logs 'Bryan is king!' to the console.
```

Hope this helps somebody. If you find a problem with the code, please be so kind as to update the Gist.

Comment: Thanks! I used this instead of a javascript sprintf solution.

Comment: doesn't work for every templates `var test = generateTemplateString('/api/${param1}/${param2}/')` 

`console.log(test({param1: 'bar', param2: 'foo'}))` return `/api/bar//`

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The regex was including a single match of ${param1}/${param2} when it should have been two matches.

Comment: Note that this one doesn't work in IE11, because of missing support for back ticks.

Comment: Of course, if template strings aren't supported by a browser, this method won't work.

If you want to use template strings in unsupported browsers, I would recommend using a language like TypeScript, or a transpiler like Babel; That's the only way to get ES6 into old browsers.

Comment: Note that this would not pass the ESLint rules in some codebases - specifically if the [no-new-func](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new-func) rule is enabled. The `Function` constructor works a bit differently (i.e. is a little safer) than `eval`, but some programmers prefer to avoid it completely for similar reasons (debugging, security).

Comment: A disclaimer - the solution I proposed _works_ - but that doesn't mean I recommend it. At the point that you're trying to get dynamic templates into your app, you're better off building your own DSL in my opinion.

Comment: Working like a chamr !

Answer (score 31):

What you're asking for here:

> ```
> //non working code quoted from the question
> let b=10;
> console.log(a.template());//b:10
> ```

is exactly equivalent (in terms of power and, er, safety) to `eval`: the ability to take a string containing code and execute that code; and also the ability for the executed code to see local variables in the caller's environment.

There is no way in JS for a function to see local variables in its caller, unless that function is `eval()`. Even `Function()` can't do it.

---

When you hear there's something called "template strings" coming to JavaScript, it's natural to assume it's a built-in template library, like Mustache. It isn't. It's mainly just [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) and multiline strings for JS. I think this is going to be a common misconception for a while, though. :(

Comment: TBH that's what I thought it was. Would have been very, very handy.

Comment: Does this (still) work? I'm getting `template is not a function`.

Comment: The code block at the top of this answer is a quote from the question. It does not work.

Answer (score 19):

There are many good solutions posted here, but none yet which utilizes the [ES6 String.raw method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw). Here is my contriubution. It has an important limitation in that it will only accept properties from a passed in object, meaning no code execution in the template will work.

```js
function parseStringTemplate(str, obj) {
    let parts = str.split(/\$\{(?!\d)[\wæøåÆØÅ]*\}/);
    let args = str.match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g) || [];
    let parameters = args.map(argument => obj[argument] || (obj[argument] === undefined ? "" : obj[argument]));
    return String.raw({ raw: parts }, ...parameters);
}
```

```js
let template = "Hello, ${name}! Are you ${age} years old?";
let values = { name: "John Doe", age: 18 };

parseStringTemplate(template, values);
// output: Hello, John Doe! Are you 18 years old?
```

1. Split string into non-argument textual parts. See [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54896977/3032543).
   `parts: ["Hello, ", "! Are you ", " years old?"]`
2. Split string into property names. Empty array if match fails.
   `args: ["name", "age"]`
3. Map parameters from `obj` by property name. Solution is limited by shallow one level mapping. Undefined values are substituted with an empty string, but other falsy values are accepted.
   `parameters: ["John Doe", 18]`
4. Utilize `String.raw(...)` and return result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what value is String.raw actually providing here? It seems you're doing all the work of parsing the string and keeping track of what the substitions are. Is this much different from simply calling `.replace()` repeatedly?

Comment: Fair point, @SteveBennett. I had some problems turning a normal string into a template string, and found a solution by building the raw object myself. I guess it reduces String.raw to a concatenation method, but I think it works quite well. I would like to see a nice solution with ```.replace()```, though :) I think readability is important, so while using regular expressions myself, I try to name them to help make sense of it all...

Comment: Yeah works like charm. Tested on React native as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

TLDR:
https://jsfiddle.net/bj89zntu/1/

Everyone seems to be worried about accessing variables. Why not just pass them? I'm sure it won't be too hard to get the variable context in the caller and pass it down. Use
[ninjagecko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-a-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference/6394168#6394168) to get the props from obj.

```
function renderString(str,obj){
    return str.replace(/\$\{.+?\}/g,(match)=>{return index(obj,match)})
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
function index(obj,is,value) {
    if (typeof is == 'string')
        is=is.split('.');
    if (is.length==1 && value!==undefined)
        return obj[is[0]] = value;
    else if (is.length==0)
        return obj;
    else
        return index(obj[is[0]],is.slice(1), value);
}

function renderString(str,obj){
    return str.replace(/\$\{.+?\}/g,(match)=>{return index(obj,match)})
}

renderString('abc${a}asdas',{a:23,b:44}) //abc23asdas
renderString('abc${a.c}asdas',{a:{c:22,d:55},b:44}) //abc22asdas
```

Comment: @s.meijer could you elaborate? I am using this code successfully. https://jsfiddle.net/w3jx07vt/

Comment: Better regex would allow you to not select the `${}` characters. Try: `/(?!\${)([^{}]*)(?=})/g`

Comment: @Relic https://jsfiddle.net/w3jx07vt/2/ I couldn't get that working, care to lend a hand and I'll update my post? :)

Comment: So the way you're trying to grab it this won't actually help much, I ended up doing a string replace instead. Instead of adding a step of interpolation, so I can use the string as interp or string. Not fancy, but it worked.

Comment: @EricHodonsky Could you elaborate on "the way I'm trying to grab it"?  Perhaps share your use case. Most of the above solutions focus on code generation, which my solution does not require. The problem here is A) Accessing the variables (which I do not do, letting the user pass them in instead), B) finding where to substitute names, C) looking up names (on an object, in this case). This works according to jsfiddle.

Comment: The fiddle code works great but the code listed in the answer here on stackoverflow does not. For some reason they're different?

Answer (score 10):

The issue here is to have a function that has access to the variables of its caller. This is why we see direct `eval` being used for template processing. A possible solution would be to generate a function taking formal parameters named by a dictionary's properties, and calling it with the corresponding values in the same order. An alternative way would be to have something simple as this:

```
var name = "John Smith";
var message = "Hello, my name is ${name}";
console.log(new Function('return `' + message + '`;')());
```

And for anyone using Babel compiler we need to create closure which remembers the environment in which it was created:

```
console.log(new Function('name', 'return `' + message + '`;')(name));
```

Comment: Your first snippet is actually worse than `eval` because it works only with a global `name` variable

Comment: @Bergi Your statement is valid  - the scope of the function will be lost. I wanted to present an easy solution to the problem and provided a simplified example of what can be done. One could simply come up with the following to overcome the problem:

`var template = function() {
var name = "John Smith";
var message = "Hello, my name is ${name}";
this.local = new Function('return `' + message + '`;')();}`

Comment: No, that's exactly what would *not* work - `new Function` doesn't have access to the `var name` in the `template` function.

Comment: The second snip fixed my problem... Up vote from me! Thanks, this helped solve a temporary problem we were having with dynamic routing to an iframe :)

Comment: could you please explain, `anyone using Babel compiler we need to create closure which remembers the environment in which it was created`?

Answer (score 10):

I liked s.meijer's answer and wrote my own version based on his:

```
function parseTemplate(template, map, fallback) {
    return template.replace(/\$\{[^}]+\}/g, (match) => 
        match
            .slice(2, -1)
            .trim()
            .split(".")
            .reduce(
                (searchObject, key) => searchObject[key] || fallback || match,
                map
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: Why the reducer?

Comment: instead of `searchObject[key]`, I had to use `searchObject.hasOwnProperty(key)` to support falsy values.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to Daniel's answer (and s.meijer's [gist](https://gist.github.com/smeijer/6580740a0ff468960a5257108af1384e)) but more readable:

```
const regex = /\${[^{]+}/g;

export default function interpolate(template, variables, fallback) {
    return template.replace(regex, (match) => {
        const path = match.slice(2, -1).trim();
        return getObjPath(path, variables, fallback);
    });
}

//get the specified property or nested property of an object
function getObjPath(path, obj, fallback = '') {
    return path.split('.').reduce((res, key) => res[key] || fallback, obj);
}
```

Note: This slightly improves s.meijer's original, since it won't match things like `${foo{bar}` (the regex only allows non-curly brace characters inside `${` and `}`).

---

UPDATE: I was asked for an example using this, so here you go:

```
const replacements = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 37
}

interpolate('My name is ${name}, and I am ${age}.', replacements)
```

Comment: Can you post an example actually using this? This javascript is a bit beyond me. I'd suggest a regex of `/\$\{(.*?)(?!\$\{)\}/g` (to handle nest curly braces). I have a working solution but I'm not sure it's as portable as yours, so I'd love to see how this should be implemented in a page. Mine also uses `eval()`.

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer as well, and I'd love your feedback on how to make that more secure and performance-minded: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294208.

Comment: @RegularJoe I added an example. My goal was to keep it simple, but you're right that if you want to handle nested curly braces, you would need to change the regex. However, I can't think of a use case for that when evaluating a regular string as if it were a template literal (the whole purpose of this function). What did you have in mind?

Comment: Also, I am neither a performance expert nor a security expert; my answer is really just combining two previous answers. But I will say that using `eval` leaves you a lot more open to possible mistakes that would cause security issues, whereas all my version is doing is looking up a property on an object from a dot-separated path, which should be safe.

Answer (score 6):

@Mateusz Moska, solution works great, but when i used it in React Native(build mode), it throws an error: **Invalid character '`'**, though it works when i run it in debug mode.

So i wrote down my own solution using regex.

```
String.prototype.interpolate = function(params) {
  let template = this
  for (let key in params) {
    template = template.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\{' + key + '\\}', 'g'), params[key])
  }
  return template
}

const template = 'Example text: ${text}',
  result = template.interpolate({
    text: 'Foo Boo'
  })

console.log(result)
```

**Demo:** https://es6console.com/j31pqx1p/

**NOTE:** Since I don't know the root cause of an issue, i raised a ticket in react-native repo, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14107, so that once they can able to fix/guide me about the same :)

Comment: this does support templates containing the back-tick character. However, rather than try to invent a templating pattern, you are probably better off just [using mustache or similar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache). depending on how complex your templates are this is a brute force approach that doesn't consider edge cases - the key could contain a special regex pattern.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the string prototype, for example

```
String.prototype.toTemplate=function(){
    return eval('`'+this+'`');
}
//...
var a="b:${b}";
var b=10;
console.log(a.toTemplate());//b:10
```

But the answer of the original question is no way.

Answer (score 4):

I required this method with support for Internet Explorer. It turned out the back ticks aren't supported by even IE11. Also; using `eval` or it's equivalent `Function` doesn't feel right.

For the one that notice; I also use backticks, but these ones are removed by compilers like babel. The methods suggested by other ones, depend on them on run-time. As said before; this is an issue in IE11 and lower.

So this is what I came up with:

```
function get(path, obj, fb = `$\{${path}}`) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((res, key) => res[key] || fb, obj);
}

function parseTpl(template, map, fallback) {
  return template.replace(/\$\{.+?}/g, (match) => {
    const path = match.substr(2, match.length - 3).trim();
    return get(path, map, fallback);
  });
}
```

Example output:

```
const data = { person: { name: 'John', age: 18 } };

parseTpl('Hi ${person.name} (${person.age})', data);
// output: Hi John (18)

parseTpl('Hello ${person.name} from ${person.city}', data);
// output: Hello John from ${person.city}

parseTpl('Hello ${person.name} from ${person.city}', data, '-');
// output: Hello John from -
```

Comment: "using eval or it's equivalent Function doesn't feel right." ... Yeah... I agree, but I think this is one of the very few use cases in which one could say, "mmhkay, let's use it". Please check https://jsperf.com/es6-string-tmpl -- it's my practical use case. Using your function (with the same regexp as mine) and mine (eval + string literals). Thanks! :)

Comment: @AndreaPuddu, your performance is indeed better. But then again; template strings are unsupported in IE. So ``eval('`' + taggedURL + '`')`` simply doesn't work.

Comment: "Seems" better I'd say, because it's tested in isolation... The only purpose of that test was to see the potential  performance issues using `eval`. Regarding template literals: thanks for pointing that out again. I'm using Babel to transpile my code but my function will still not work apparently 

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this implementation and it works like a charm.

```
function interpolateTemplate(template: string, args: any): string {
  return Object.entries(args).reduce(
    (result, [arg, val]) => result.replace(`$\{${arg}}`, `${val}`),
    template,
  )
}

const template = 'This is an example: ${name}, ${age} ${email}'

console.log(interpolateTemplate(template,{name:'Med', age:'20', email:'example@abc.com'}))
```

You could raise an error if arg is not found in template

Comment: While fine for simple property binding, this doesn't support template nesting or other expressions in the usual way. You have to evaluate any nested templates or nested expressions before passing them to interpolateTemplate.

Answer (score 3):

I currently can't comment on existing answers so I am unable to directly comment on Bryan Raynor's excellent response. Thus, this response is going to update his answer with a slight correction.

In short, his function fails to actually cache the created function, so it will always recreate, regardless of whether it's seen the template before. Here is the corrected code:

```
    /**
     * Produces a function which uses template strings to do simple interpolation from objects.
     * 
     * Usage:
     *    var makeMeKing = generateTemplateString('${name} is now the king of ${country}!');
     * 
     *    console.log(makeMeKing({ name: 'Bryan', country: 'Scotland'}));
     *    // Logs 'Bryan is now the king of Scotland!'
     */
    var generateTemplateString = (function(){
        var cache = {};

        function generateTemplate(template){
            var fn = cache[template];

            if (!fn){
                // Replace ${expressions} (etc) with ${map.expressions}.

                var sanitized = template
                    .replace(/\$\{([\s]*[^;\s\{]+[\s]*)\}/g, function(_, match){
                        return `\$\{map.${match.trim()}\}`;
                    })
                    // Afterwards, replace anything that's not ${map.expressions}' (etc) with a blank string.
                    .replace(/(\$\{(?!map\.)[^}]+\})/g, '');

                fn = cache[template] = Function('map', `return \`${sanitized}\``);
            }

            return fn;
        };

        return generateTemplate;
    })();
```

Answer (score 2):

Still dynamic but seems more controlled than just using a naked eval:

```
const vm = require('vm')
const moment = require('moment')


let template = '### ${context.hours_worked[0].value} \n Hours worked \n #### ${Math.abs(context.hours_worked_avg_diff[0].value)}% ${fns.gt0(context.hours_worked_avg_diff[0].value, "more", "less")} than usual on ${fns.getDOW(new Date())}'
let context = {
  hours_worked:[{value:10}],
  hours_worked_avg_diff:[{value:10}],

}


function getDOW(now) {
  return moment(now).locale('es').format('dddd')
}

function gt0(_in, tVal, fVal) {
  return _in >0 ? tVal: fVal
}



function templateIt(context, template) {
  const script = new vm.Script('`'+template+'`')
  return script.runInNewContext({context, fns:{getDOW, gt0 }})
}

console.log(templateIt(context, template))
```

https://repl.it/IdVt/3

Answer (score 1):

This solution works without ES6:

```
function render(template, opts) {
  return new Function(
    'return new Function (' + Object.keys(opts).reduce((args, arg) => args += '\'' + arg + '\',', '') + '\'return `' + template.replace(/(^|[^\\])'/g, '$1\\\'') + '`;\'' +
    ').apply(null, ' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(opts).reduce((vals, key) => vals.push(opts[key]) && vals, [])) + ');'
  )();
}

render("hello ${ name }", {name:'mo'}); // "hello mo"
```

Note: the `Function` constructor is always created in the global scope, which could potentially cause global variables to be overwritten by the template, e.g. `render("hello ${ someGlobalVar = 'some new value' }", {name:'mo'});`

Answer (score 1):

You should try this tiny JS module, by Andrea Giammarchi, from github :
https://github.com/WebReflection/backtick-template

```
/*! (C) 2017 Andrea Giammarchi - MIT Style License */
function template(fn, $str, $object) {'use strict';
  var
    stringify = JSON.stringify,
    hasTransformer = typeof fn === 'function',
    str = hasTransformer ? $str : fn,
    object = hasTransformer ? $object : $str,
    i = 0, length = str.length,
    strings = i < length ? [] : ['""'],
    values = hasTransformer ? [] : strings,
    open, close, counter
  ;
  while (i < length) {
    open = str.indexOf('${', i);
    if (-1 < open) {
      strings.push(stringify(str.slice(i, open)));
      open += 2;
      close = open;
      counter = 1;
      while (close < length) {
        switch (str.charAt(close++)) {
          case '}': counter -= 1; break;
          case '{': counter += 1; break;
        }
        if (counter < 1) {
          values.push('(' + str.slice(open, close - 1) + ')');
          break;
        }
      }
      i = close;
    } else {
      strings.push(stringify(str.slice(i)));
      i = length;
    }
  }
  if (hasTransformer) {
    str = 'function' + (Math.random() * 1e5 | 0);
    if (strings.length === values.length) strings.push('""');
    strings = [
      str,
      'with(this)return ' + str + '([' + strings + ']' + (
        values.length ? (',' + values.join(',')) : ''
      ) + ')'
    ];
  } else {
    strings = ['with(this)return ' + strings.join('+')];
  }
  return Function.apply(null, strings).apply(
    object,
    hasTransformer ? [fn] : []
  );
}

template.asMethod = function (fn, object) {'use strict';
  return typeof fn === 'function' ?
    template(fn, this, object) :
    template(this, fn);
};
```

Demo (all the following tests return true):

```
const info = 'template';
// just string
`some ${info}` === template('some ${info}', {info});

// passing through a transformer
transform `some ${info}` === template(transform, 'some ${info}', {info});

// using it as String method
String.prototype.template = template.asMethod;

`some ${info}` === 'some ${info}'.template({info});

transform `some ${info}` === 'some ${info}'.template(transform, {info});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my own solution doing a type with a description as a function

```
export class Foo {
...
description?: Object;
...
}

let myFoo:Foo = {
...
  description: (a,b) => `Welcome ${a}, glad to see you like the ${b} section`.
...
}
```

and so doing:

```
let myDescription = myFoo.description('Bar', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim (This way):

```js
let a = 'b:${this.b}'
let b = 10

function template(templateString, templateVars) {
    return new Function('return `' + templateString + '`').call(templateVars)
}

result.textContent = template(a, {b})
```

```html
<b id=result></b>
```

Comment: Another example:
```const dados = {nome: 'Marquinhos', email: 'xiii@marquinhos.com'};template('${this.nome} utiliza esse email: ${this.email}!', dados)```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this solution

```js
const interpolate = (str) =>
  new Function(`return \`${new String(str)}\`;`)();

const foo = 'My';

const obj = {
  text: 'Hanibal Lector',
  firstNum: 1,
  secondNum: 2
}
 
const str = "${foo} name is : ${obj.text}. sum = ${obj.firstNum} + ${obj.secondNum} = ${obj.firstNum + obj.secondNum}";

console.log(interpolate(str));
```

by returning a new function that has a template literal that copies the full string into that template literal you achieve the correct variable expansion wanted - this is useful if you want to have strings saved in some content management system that you then want to expand.

The code also includes an example of this working.

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

Option1:

```
function replaceTemplate(templateString, objContext) {
        return templateString.replace(/\${[A-Za-z0-9_\$]+}/ig, (data) => { const key = data.replace(/^\${/, '').replace(/}$/, ''); return objContext[key] || data })
     }
```

or

Option2:

```
function replaceTemplate(templateString) {
    return templateString.replace(/\${[A-Za-z0-9_\$]+}/ig, (data) => { const key = data.replace(/^\${/, '').replace(/}$/, ''); return this[key] || data })
}
```

example

```
const fruits = { apple: 1, banana: 3, stringValue: 'a: ${apple}, b: ${banana}'} 
replaceTemplate(fruits.stringValue, fruits) // Option1: 
// or 
replaceTemplate.bind(fruits)(fruits.stringValue) //Option2: 

output: 'apple: 1, banana: 3, orange: ${orange}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Since we're reinventing the wheel on something that would be a lovely feature in javascript.

I use `eval()`, which is not secure, but javascript is not secure. I readily admit that I'm not excellent with javascript, but I had a need, and I needed an answer so I made one.

I chose to stylize my variables with an `@` rather than an `$`, particularly because I want to use the multiline feature of literals *without* evaluating til it's ready. So variable syntax is `@{OptionalObject.OptionalObjectN.VARIABLE_NAME}`

I am no javascript expert, so I'd gladly take advice on improvement but...

```
var prsLiteral, prsRegex = /\@\{(.*?)(?!\@\{)\}/g
for(i = 0; i < myResultSet.length; i++) {
    prsLiteral = rt.replace(prsRegex,function (match,varname) {
        return eval(varname + "[" + i + "]");
        // you could instead use return eval(varname) if you're not looping.
    })
    console.log(prsLiteral);
}
```

A very simple implementation follows

```js
myResultSet = {totalrecords: 2,
Name: ["Bob", "Stephanie"],
Age: [37,22]};

rt = `My name is @{myResultSet.Name}, and I am @{myResultSet.Age}.`

var prsLiteral, prsRegex = /\@\{(.*?)(?!\@\{)\}/g
for(i = 0; i < myResultSet.totalrecords; i++) {
    prsLiteral = rt.replace(prsRegex,function (match,varname) {
        return eval(varname + "[" + i + "]");
        // you could instead use return eval(varname) if you're not looping.
    })
    console.log(prsLiteral);
}
```

In my actual implementation, I choose to use `@{{variable}}`. One more set of braces. Absurdly unlikely to encounter that unexpectedly. The regex for that would look like `/\@\{\{(.*?)(?!\@\{\{)\}\}/g`

To make that easier to read

```
\@\{\{    # opening sequence, @{{ literally.
(.*?)     # capturing the variable name
          # ^ captures only until it reaches the closing sequence
(?!       # negative lookahead, making sure the following
          # ^ pattern is not found ahead of the current character
  \@\{\{  # same as opening sequence, if you change that, change this
)
\}\}      # closing sequence.
```

If you're not experienced with regex, a pretty safe rule is to escape every non-alphanumeric character, and don't *ever* needlessly escape letters as many escaped letters have special meaning to virtually all flavors of regex.

Answer (score -4):

I realize I am late to the game, but you could:

```js
const a =  (b) => `b:${b}`;

let b = 10;
console.log(a(b)); // b:10
```

Comment: This does not "create a template string as a usual string" which was one of the requirements in the OP.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think many people who think they want what OP is asking would be better served by this solution.