# How can I construct a Template String from a regular string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

So I have this `string`:

```
var name = "Chaim";
var templateStr = "Hello, my name is ${name}";
```

How can I convert it into a template-string so that the result would be equal to:

```
var template = `Hello, my name is ${name}`;
```

Is there a way to programmatically construct a Template literal?

Comment: You cannot without `eval`, and I don't think you want that. Why not just use a template string in the first place?

Comment: Because I want to pass a dynamic string to be used as the template.

Comment: @haim770 Why can't the dynamic string be a Template literal?

Comment: Because it's returned from the server as part of an Http response.

Comment: @Bergi, Apparently, template strings already are implicitly `eval`. For example: `\`hi ${alert()}\``

Comment: @haim770: Yes, they are - and imo that's a problem. Where do your dynamic strings come from?

Comment: @Bergi, As I already mentioned, they're being returned from the server (Ajax request).

Comment: @haim770: Yeah, I meant where does the server get the strings from, who inserts them? Are they user-generated? Hard-coded?

Comment: They are hard-coded in a resource file used for language translations. I do understand the security risk though. I guess my intention to use this mechanism as a "poor-man's templating-system" was wrong.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29182244/218196, but @Bergi's answer is better ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: It still is imo. And Jason Orendorffs answer there nails it.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah. Maybe you can post your answer over there as well. Or don't. I just liked your answer :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there a way to programmatically construct a Template literal?

No. "programmatically" and "literal" are antithetic (except you are in the realms of compilers).

*Template strings* should better have been named *interpolated string literals* or so. Please [**do not confuse them with *templates***](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-March/042166.html). If you want to use dynamically created strings for templates, use a template engine of your choice.

Of course template literals might help with the implementation of such, and you might get away with something simple as

```
function assemble(literal, params) {
    return new Function(params, "return `"+literal+"`;"); // TODO: Proper escaping
//             ^^^^^^^^ working in real ES6 environments only, of course
}
var template = assemble("Hello, my name is ${name}", "name");
template("Chaim"); // Hello, my name is Chaim
```

Comment: `Template strings should better have been named interpolated string literals` - Aren't they called as Quasi literals?

Comment: The programmatically ≠ litteral is the key here.

Comment: This is dangerous as it basically `eval()`s the string.

Comment: @adjenks Yes, you need to make sure that the `literal` is a valid and safe value. It's dangerous only when you do not control the value.