# How to interpolate a tagged template string with a dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings, tagged-templates

I would like to interpolate a template string (defined elsewhere):

```
const url = `www.example.com/${query}/current.json`;
```

with a dynamic value (for example, "es6") into this:

```
"www.example.com/es6/current.json"
```

For example, if i had something like this:

```
function makeRequest(url, query){
  // how do I generate my final url, here from the url and query?
}

// somehwere else:
makeRequest(url, query)
```

Is tagged template strings and a tag function the way to go? I've seen many different examples but none that fit this particular situation.

Comment: you just have to put $ before {}`\`www.example.com/${query}/current.json\`;`

Comment: So, `var query = 'es6'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined elsewhere"? You might confuse [*template literals* with templates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771751/1048572)

Comment: Sorry I think I wasn't very clear - just edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly the reason functions were invented!

```js
const dynamicUrl = query => `www.example.com/${query}/current.json`

console.log(dynamicUrl('es6')) //=> 'www.example.com/es6/current.json'
```

Comment: @zok Don't forget to `encodeURIComponent(query)` or make sure `query` is URL-safe.