# Javascript: How to use Template Literals with JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, template-literals

I discovered [Javascript ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) today. Just one word: Awesome!

**Question:** How to store and load Template Literals as JSON? I load some files via XHR, followed by some `JSON.parse()` which doesn't support `` ` `` instead of `"`, so it seems one can't save Template Literals directly in the files.

**Goal:** To use this for dynamic strings and translation and to get rid of confusing stuff like `("Hello " + username + "! How are you?")` which requires multiple strings to be stored for just one message, and instead save my stuff beautifully and simple as

```
`Hello, ${username}! How are you?`
```

where **username** points to the dynamic variable with the same name. Is that possible? If yes, how to achieve this? It's okay if i have to use a function to somehow convert the strings into Template Literals as long as it doesn't hit hard on the overall performance, but I would like to at least avoid `eval`.

Comment: These literals are code not strings. You can not store them as JSON. but you can use functions. `var tplHello = ({username}) => \`Hello, ${username}! How are you?\`` and use it as `var data={ username: "foo" }, text = tplHello(data);`

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. It seems i have confused template literals with "dynamic strings", just as you say. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771597/how-can-i-construct-a-template-string-from-a-regular-string converting a string into a template literal would be implicitly the same as **eval** as variable lookup always needs code to be executed. Seems like my hope for an easy translation system or "dynamic "strings" was fueled by a misconception. Off-Topic: I guess using RegEx for replacing %username (or similar) in the strings would fit what i want to achieve better.

Answer (score 12):

You can create your own function to parse template literal,

```js
function stringTemplateParser(expression, valueObj) {
  const templateMatcher = /{{\s?([^{}\s]*)\s?}}/g;
  let text = expression.replace(templateMatcher, (substring, value, index) => {
    value = valueObj[value];
    return value;
  });
  return text
}

console.log(stringTemplateParser('my name is {{name}} and age is {{age}}', {name: 'Tom', age:100}));


// output 'my name is Tom and age is 100'
```

Comment: to use the ${variable} format, use this function instead:

`function stringTemplateParser(expression, valueObj) {
  const templateMatcher = /\${\s?([^{}\s]*)\s?}/g;
  let text = expression.replace(templateMatcher, (substring, value, index) => {
    value = valueObj[value];
    return value;
  });
  return text
}`

Answer (score 4):

You could always use `JSON.stringify` to enclose dynamic data:

```
const data = 'some value';
JSON.stringify({
  data,
});
// expected: "{\"data\": \"some value\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to separate the problem in a few substrings of JSON. Create the key "message" and this key stores parts of the message. It also works well for i18n.

```
{
  "message" : {
    "_0": "first part ",
    "_1": "after first variable. ",
    "_2": "after another variable"
  }
}
```

And then, after decoding it, you can access it like
`${message._0}${variable}${message._1}${var2}${message._2}`

Answer (score 0):

Try [json-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-templates). Looks like exactly what you're looking for.