# printf each with an Object node #8774

Tags: javascript, printf, jestjs

```js
// Returns Testing [Object object]
describe.skip.each([[{foo: 'abc'}], [{foo: 'bca'}]])('Testing %s', ...
```

```js
// Returns Testing {foo: 'abc'}
describe.skip.each([[{foo: 'abc'}], [{foo: 'bca'}]])('Testing %o', ...
```

Is it possible do something like...

```js
// Expect Testing abc
describe.skip.each([[{foo: 'abc'}], [{foo: 'bca'}]])('Testing %o.foo', ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is not possible with that API but with the [second API it is](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#2-describeeach-table-name-fn-timeout)

```js
describe.each`
    column
    ${{ foo: 'abc' }}
    ${{ foo: 'bca' }}
    `
    ('Testing $column.foo', ({ column }) => {
        ...
    })
```

**Update**

[Sadly you cannot build a template literal programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771597/how-can-i-construct-a-template-string-from-a-regular-string), [here's how tagged template literals work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)
The `${expresion}`is needed to identify the data you want to pass.

Comment: Works!

But just works when I use the columns inside the each string. Is it possible make an constant that I can use to others tests?

Comment: `describe.each\`
     tests
      ${testCases}
    \``

Where `testCases` are my column lines

Comment: +1 because you mention the documentation and using documentation I could conform that we could use "$" + the property name when we are using "regular" [{...}, {...}]