# Template Engines in Light of Now Inherent ES6-Template-Strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, template-engine

There are a number of Template Engines one can use when developing with Express + node.js.

However, now node.js 4.2.2 inherently supports ES6-Template-Strings:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en#multiline-strings
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literal-lexical-components

In light of this inherent support for templates strings, what are the advantages of still using a template engines like ejs? Do any current template engines utilize ES6-Template-Strings? Are there any performance tests that compare Express Template Engines to straight ES6-Template-Strings?

Comment: Despite the name "template strings", string interpolation using template literals [is not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29201948/1048572) as a templating engine.

Comment: see [How Does ES6 Templating Compare to Existing JavaScript Templating Solutions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34058667/1048572)