# Can we get away with replacing existing JS templating solutions with ES6 templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, ecmascript-6, benchmarking

One very attractive feature of ES6 is its built in template strings.  At this point in time, since transpiling to ES5 is a must for cross browser compatibility, I am curious what the performance differences are between transpiled ES6 templates and existing solutions such as Mustache, Handlebars, Jade etc.  Obviously if you need advanced features from a templating language, ES6 templates may not fulfill all of your needs, but if you are performing basic templating, is it fair to say that ES6 template strings could replace your current templating engine?

Comment: Since we're talking about transpiled code: At some point, with both ES6 Template Strings and a templating engine, they are going to have to concatenate strings in the ES5 way: `"Hello, " + name`. So the bottleneck will be applying those changes to the DOM, not creating the string in the first place, so you can't really compare them.

Comment: Despite the name "template strings", string interpolation using template literals is not the same as a templating engine.

Comment: @RGraham For the sake of this question, lets assume the entire page is one template.  Essentially the question boils down to:  Can we get away with replacing existing JS templating solutions with ES6 templates?  Changing the question to reflect this more accurately.

Comment: @wikiwong Then no. ES6 template strings are *very* basic. Templating engines have many additional features like looping/iteration, HTML sanitization to name a few major ones. If you want to compare *only* performance, ES6 interpolation will be faster than rendering a template but only because the templating engine needs to do preprocessing (parsing/transforming) for additional features.

Answer (score 1):

Template *strings* in ES6 aren't really related to the various template *engines* that are implemented in JavaScript.

Most template engines (Underscore, Lodash, Mustache, Handlebars, Jade, etc) all have special syntaxes and special forms. Some might give you the ability to define blocks, use special mark up for various things, or giving you unique tags for logic/looping structures.

ES6 [Template Strings](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#template-strings) give you the full power of JavaScript without asking you to learn a specialized/opinionated template engine.

```
// underscore
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
// => "hello: moe"

// ES6 Template String
let name = 'moe';
`hello: ${name}`;
// => "hello: moe"
```

Notice the ugly `<%= %>` tags in the underscore template? That's just something underscore invented to solve a "problem"; the "problem" being that before ES6, JavaScript didn't have any sort of [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). People thought it was tedious to write things like

```
var greeting = "hello";
var name     = "moe";
var emotion  = "depressed";

greeting + ", my name is " + name + ". I feel " + emotion + ".";
// => "hello, my name is moe. I feel depressed."
```

With ES6, JavaScript gets native string interpolation via `${...}`. Pretty much anything can go inside `${}` as long as it's valid JavaScript.

```
let name = "alice";
let emotion = "happy";
`${greeting || "hi"}, my name is ${name}. I feel ${emotion}.`
// => "hi, my name is alice. I feel happy."
```

Comment: OP seems to know about templates and is just asking about performance difference between third party templating functions/engine and the native ES6 string interpolation.

Comment: @ShanShan: You cannot compare performance of two calls that do different things.

Comment: Thanks for the response @naomik.  I would argue that ES6 template strings are very related to the various existing JavaScript templating engines.  Especially when you introduce [tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings).  Ultimately I am questioning the necessity of third party JavaScript templating engines with the introduction of template strings in ES6.

Comment: @wikiwong I would say there's no need for template engines in ES5 though either. I'm sorry you got that impression from my post.

Answer (score -1):

If you transpile, ES6 get transpiled to native ES5 so it should beat any framework/library performance wise.

**ES6**

```
var foo = "foo";
var bar = "bar";
var foobar = `${foo} ${bar}`;
```

**Transpiled**

```
"use strict";

var foo = "foo";
var bar = "bar";
var foobar = foo + " " + bar;
```

Comment: ES6 doesn't get transpiled to ES5... unless you transpile it. It's not some sort of automatic thing.

Comment: Read the question maybe? OP specifically talks about **transpiled** ES6...  What I tried to say is ES6 templates don't get transpiled to some weird stuff with library imports and so on (IF you transpile it, precision is needed it seems), you just get plain old native javascript.

Comment: The point of transpilation is that you get plain old ES5, yes, that's no different for template literals. Now what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Templating engines work at runtime, transpilation is done once and for all before.

Comment: @ShanShan I'm referring to after the code has already been transpiled. My curiosity is in the performance of ES6 resolution of template strings vs existing JS templating solutions.

Comment: I understood your question. When you transpile ES6 templates, you get native string concatenation and that beats any library/templating engine doing it on the fly at runtime. Why so many people don't understand what I'm saying? It seems pretty clear. **native** string concatenation should be faster than templating engine.

Comment: @ShanShan The confusing part is that your *transpiled* output could actually be an implementation of a rudimentary templating engine, making both *transpiled ES6* and this *templating engine* equivalent. So your assertion that it should *beat any framework/library* is somewhat invalid.

Comment: @RGraham Without even talking of the usefulness of a such rudimentary templating engine, even if it has only one function with 5 lines of code, it would at the very least parse the template before concatenation or call `string.replace()` few times. So, simple string concatenation beats (parsing followed by string concatenation or few `string.replace()`).

Comment: @ShanShan Unless they are doing their own templating, but yes that's a fair point. You should put that in your answer!