# Evaluating a string inside a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals

I know the basic working of JavaScript template literals.

```
var name = 'nithin'
console.log(`hello ${name}`) 
//this will print "hello nithin"
```

What if my template literal is stored in a DB and I'm dynamically querying the DB to get the corresponding template literal? How can I evaluate this?

**This is my scenario:**

I have store the template literal in DB as a string since I can't store it with backticks:

```
"welcome ${user}"
```

And I'm querying the DB for the string. Suppose I have this string in the variable `stringFromDB`. Now I want to evaluate this string using template literal method.

I have tried the following, but it isn't working:

```
eval(`stringFromDb`)
```

I have a variable named `user` in the same scope which is having a value `"nithin"`. Im expecting `"welcome nithin"` as result. Any help?

Comment: Note: It's called *template literal*.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string

Comment: tl;dr: template literals are not templates. Use Handlebars or similar.