# Using TypeMoq Mock With Angular TestBed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I've defined a `FooService` as follows

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
export interface Foo {
    Foo(): string;
}

@Injectable()
export class FooService implements Foo {
    Foo(): string {
        return "Fooey!";
    }
}
```

and a `BarComponent` like this

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {FooService} from "./foo.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: 'module.id',
    template: '<h1>Bar Component</h1>'
})
export class BarComponent {
    constructor(private fooService: FooService) {}

    doFoo(): string {
        return(this.fooService.Foo());
    }
}
```

Now I want to test my `BarComponent` and I'd like to use `TypeMoq` to mock the `FooService`, so I did the following

```
import * as TypeMoq from 'typemoq';
import {Foo, FooService} from "./foo.service";
import {TestBed, async} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {BarComponent} from "./bar.component";

describe('BarComponent', () => {
    let component: BarComponent;
    let mockFooService: TypeMoq.IMock<Foo>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        mockFooService = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType<Foo>();
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [BarComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: FooService, useValue: mockFooService.object}]
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BarComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('does something', () => {
        mockFooService.setup(x => x.Foo()).returns(() => "FooBar!");
        expect(component.doFoo()).toEqual("FooBar!");
    });

});
```

However running the above gives the following error

```
SyntaxError: Function arg string contains parenthesis
        at new Function (<anonymous>)
        at evalExpression (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25431:25 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:59412:40)
        at jitStatements (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25448:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:59429:12)
        at JitCompiler._compileModule (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25658:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:59639:35)
        at createResult (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25613:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:59594:106)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25616:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:59597:40)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:25559:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:59540:23)
        at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler/testing.es5.js:475:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:68201:31)
        at TestBed._initIfNeeded (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:705:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:21376:36)
        at TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:791:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:21462:14)
        at Function.TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:610:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:21281:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/auth/login/bar.component.spec.ts:19:30 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:99954:41)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65763:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65294:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:364:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65762:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65523:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65010:34)
        at webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:96:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:20767:17
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65763:26)
        at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:64605:39)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65291:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:364:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65762:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65523:43)
        at AsyncTestZoneSpec._finishCallback (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:91:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:20762:25)
        at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:38:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:64594:31
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65796:31)
        at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65563:47)
        at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:460:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65858:38)
        at timer (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1732:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:67130:29)
```

Is it possible to use `TypeMoq`'s with the angular `TestBed` and if so how do you do it correctly?

Answer (score 8):

I was running into this also, it's coming in because of how you're doing your providers.

Change

```
providers: [{ provide: FooService, useValue: mockFooService.object}]
```

to

```
providers: [{ provide: FooService, useFactory: () => { return mockFooService.object } }]
```

Using the factory function to return got rid of errors for me.  If you use useClass you'll get an error about param.map is not a function, and if you use useValue you get an error about unexpected parenthesis.  useFactory and just an inline function that returns the moq.object works, though.

Comment: This caught my eye. Why exactly are we getting an error while using the `useValue` provider configuration though?

Comment: When I try to do it this way, I'm seeing an error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object  at Function.getPrototypeOf (native)` :-( I have a very similar setup

Comment: I was getting `SyntaxError: Arg string terminates parameters early` instead with angular 6 (for useValue). Wondering why too.

Comment: @PavelSapehin I stumbled over this rare issue because of using `new this.constructor()` instead of `new this()` in context of a static method of an ES6 class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error. "**Arg string terminates parameters early**" .
I did the solution like this.

```js
let params = {
  "NO": 1,
  "ID": 2,
  "FIELD.SECOND": "Test"
};
let text = "${NO} test interpolate ${ID}";

const names = Object.keys(params);
//if you remove this loop you got error
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  names[i] = names[i].split('.').join("")
}
const vals = Object.values(params);
try {
  console.log(new Function(...names, `return \`${text}\`;`)(...vals));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```