# React-Intl: Load new strings from api response

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I have a component that needs strings from the backend. I currently request the `.po` file from the server, convert it to `.json` and return it to my React component. I then want to be able to display those strings whilst replacing the correct values in the string, i.e.

```
<FormattedMessage id={dynamicId} values={dynamicVals} />
```

dynamicId is pulled from a separate api call, as well as dynamicVals.

My problem is that these strings are not bundled like all of my other app strings, so `react-intl` is unaware of them. How can I add these strings to the library client-side/async? I've attempted using `defineMessages` and `addLocaleData`, but I either am doing something incorrectly, or am not using the right api methods. Does `addLocaleData` provide the means to adding strings to the library? Is this possible to do?

**In summary:**

How can I receive

```
{
  notifications.friendships.nowfriends: "{name} is now your friend"
}
```

from the api and display it using:

```
<FormattedMessage id='notifications.friendships.nowfriends' values={{ name: 'StackOver Bro' }} />
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried ` id={notifications.friendships.nowfriends}`

Comment: yes, of course. but react-intl does not have any reference to that id. I'm wondering how to add the string to the library from within the react component where i make the api call and display the strings

Comment: I didn't use the library before so I'm just guessing. Can you use [`addlocaledata`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#addlocaledata) with the result of your API call? Or [`definemessages`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#definemessages)

Comment: I’ve attempted both those things but to no avail. It’s very possible I’m doing it incorrectly though. I haven’t really been able to find any examples of what I’m trying to do.

Comment: If you haven't tried can you try `<FormattedMessage defaultMessage={notifications.friendships.nowfriends} values={{ name: 'StackOver Bro' }} />`

Comment: using `defaultMessage` yields this result: `[React Intl] Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction.`

Comment: Does it work when you type manually `defaultMessage='{name} is now your friend'`

Comment: Honestly i think react-intl isn't just friendly for that usecase...it is build on a flow where strings live in your app and get extracted and parsed and bundled using webpack. You might give react-i18next a try: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next based on i18next it is build around the loading translations from server via xhr and take care of loading is done before showing your components.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It guided me to abandon using React-intl for this use case!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to know what I ended up doing...

Since I already had the strings and the variables to interpolate with, I bypassed the localization library and just used the following function (thanks to the answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string), especially @user2501097 and @Bryan Rayner)

```
/**
 *  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string
 *
 * Produces a function which uses template strings to do simple interpolation from objects.
 *
 * Usage:
 *    var makeMeKing = generateTemplateString('${name} is now the king of {country}!');
 *
 *    console.log(makeMeKing({ name: 'Bryan', country: 'Scotland'}));
 *    // Logs 'Bryan is now the king of Scotland!'
 */
const generateTemplateString = (function () {
    const cache = {}

    function generateTemplate(template) {
        let fn = cache[template]

        if (!fn) {
            // Replace ${expressions} (etc) with ${map.expressions}.
            const sanitized = template
                .replace(/\$?\{([\s]*[^;\s\{]+[\s]*)\}/g, (_, match) => {
                    return `\$\{map.${match.trim()}\}`
                })
                // Afterwards, replace anything that's not ${map.expressions}' (etc) with a blank string.
                .replace(/(\$\{(?!map\.)[^}]+\})/g, '')

            fn = Function('map', `return \`${sanitized}\``)
            cache[template] = fn
        }

        return fn
    }

    return generateTemplate
}())

export default generateTemplateString
```