# Assign text to variable inside the String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am saving string into mongoDB with preset variable as

```
'Current time is ${time}'
```

After that I am retrieving somewhere else this string and would like to assign value to `time`

It would look something like this

```
const time = '15:50'    
const response = result //saves string retreived from mongo

res.json({
   response: response
})
```

But that returns `'Current time is ${time}'` instead of `'Current time is 15:50'`

I am aware that the string should be in `` instead of single quotes for variable to work, not sure though how to implement that as output from mongo

Anyone could point me to correct direction?

Comment: You have to use backticks instead of simple quotes `\`` instead of `'` for that string : `\`Current time is ${time}\``

Comment: it is retrieved from mongo automatically as string in single quotes, I know it must be in backticks I was wondering if there is any way to transform it.

Comment: You could also use `String.replace`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is an example of interpolation magic, as mentioned in other answer ;) Note, than even without the `evil()` ;)

```js
var time = '15:50' 
var response = 'Current time is ${time}'

var converted = (_=>(new Function(`return\`${response}\`;`))())()

console.log(converted)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to pass the string and parameters to a function and `reduce` over the parameters object:

```js
var str = 'Current time is ${time}';
var params = { time: '13:30' };

function merge(str, params) {
  return Object.keys(params).reduce((out, key) => {
    return str.replace(`\${${key}}`, params[key]);
  }, '');
}

console.log(merge(str, params));
```

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation is not performed on a string variable that happens to contain a template literal placeholder. In order for interpolation to happen, you must have a *literal string* in the code, enclosed in back ticks with a placeholder:

```
let time = '15:50';
let message = `Current time is ${time}`
console.log(message); // "Current time is 15:50"
```

If you must store strings in your database, you'll have to come up with your own mechanism for interpolating your placeholders.