# Evaluate es6 template literals without eval() and new Function

Tags: templates, ecmascript-6, eval

I have a set of strings coming from my server-side api in the format:

```
  "`Employee age is ${employeeAge}`"
```

I want to evaluate this string in a function which has reference to 'employeeAge'.

The possible ways are to use eval() :

```
 const employeeAge = 34;
 const string = eval("`Employee age is ${employeeAge}`")
```

expected result = "Employee age is 34"

or using  [new Function]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function   method

Is there any way to avoid using these methods?

Thanks

Comment: Parse it yourself?

Comment: Where would the value of `employeeAge` come from without `eval`? `eval` is the only way to access random variables in a scope by name.

Comment: please read the question again. I have updated it

Comment: I think this is one of the few appropriate uses of `eval`, IF you sanitise and trust the input. The alternative would be to run a parser through it which you pass an object with the keys that may be referenced

Comment: Yeah my suggestion would be parse it with an ES6 parser to validate that it is only a template literal with variable names, and then run it with `new Function` and explicitly pass in every variable you want to expose to ensure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31999948/4554754  this solution looks quite good