# Ionic 4 + Angular - String interpolation to JSON string

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, string-interpolation

I have the following JSON,

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "command":"begin ${{password}}",
      "name":"Initialization",
      "description":"Send SMS begin+password"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I pass data to ${{password}} to get the filled string using the passed value?

I tried to use interpolation function as described on the following topic but without any success.

[Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Does Angular, Ionic provide some built-in functions for this?

Comment: You made up this JSON or you are getting it from somwhere?

Comment: I'm able to edit the JSON file.

Comment: But JSON with using single quotes is not valid JSON.
"command":'begin ${password}'. I want to set variable to class scope and print JSON value to template. Interpolated value in JSON should be replaced by the value set in the Class Scope.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var password = 'StackOverflow';
var json_string = `{
  "commands": [
    {
      "command":"begin ${password}",
      "name":"Initialization",
      "description":"Send SMS begin+password"
    }
  ]
}`;

console.log(json_string);
```

Well, you could just use backticks (``) and make it a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), since you could edit the json file as discussed in the comments. Also, you need to have placeholders for variable's value to take effect. So change `${{password}}` to `${password}`.

Comment: Thanks for code snippet, but seems that JSON content cannot be attached dynamically.

private modifyData(data:any) {
    let json_string = ``+JSON.stringify(data)+``;
    return JSON.parse(json_string);

Does not changing data in placeholders.

Comment: @redrom You have the json data in a file. So, have backticks and placeholder changes in the file there and read it in your `modifyData()`.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around solved using replace in this way:

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "command":"begin |password| and |ipAddress|",
      "name":"Initialization",
      "description":"Send SMS begin+password"
    }
  ]
}

private modifyData(data:any) {
    let stringifiedData  = JSON.stringify(data).replace("|password|", this.password).replace("|ipAddress|", this.ipAddress);
    return JSON.parse(stringifiedData);
  }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This isn't technically templating but a simple string replace.