# Javascript string interpolation not working from text input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement string interpolation by letting user provide template from the form.

Consider these inputs:

- Input with id `mapping_template`
- Input with id `key`
- Input with id `value`

When users type following in inputs:

1. `mapping_template` has value `${key} = ${value}`
2. `key` has value `a key`
3. `value` has value `the value`

This is my function, I invoke it like so `interpolateMappingTemplate (mapping_template, 'a key', 'the value')` :

```
var interpolateMappingTemplate = function(mappingTemplate, key, value) {
  return `${templateString}`;
}
```

I was expecting when I interpolate template to get this `a key = the value` but instead my function outputs `${key} = ${value}`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot convert the content of a variable into a template string just by "wrapping" it in backticks -> [Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Comment: can you make that an answer?