# How would you turn a JavaScript variable into a Template literal?

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

I would like to take text that I generated and stored in a string and use it like a template literal.

```
var generatedText = "Pretend this text was generated and then stored in a variable. "; 
generatedText = "But I still need to use it as a template it to get ${variable}.";

var variable = "Successs!!!!";

console.log(generatedText);
//prints 'But I still need to interpolate it to get ${variable}.'
//how can I make it print using variable in it like a template as if it were doing this
console.log(`But I still need to use it as a template it to get ${variable}.`);
//prints 'But I still need to use it as a template it to get Successs!!!!.'
```

How can I get generated text to become a template string?

generatedText must start in a variable so I need to find a way to convert it to a template string if possible.

Edit:

I didn't think I would have to put this but also I don't want to use eval to risk evaluating random code...

Comment: Why not directly use template literal instead of first saving as string and than trying as template literal ? what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @MeirKeller comments aren't meant for answers. If you think you have a good answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string

Comment: See also "Can ES6 template literals be substituted at runtime" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string

Comment: Reopening because none of the top several answers of the duplicate are as good as CertainPerformance’s. There are some near the bottom that are close, but it also seems that nested properties aren’t required here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the general situation, you can use a replacer function to replace every occurrence of `${someProp}` with the `someProp` property on an object:

```js
const interpolate = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\${([^}]+)}/g,
  (_, prop) => obj[prop]
);

const generatedText = "But I still need to use it as a template it to get ${variable}.";
const variable = "Successs!!!!";

console.log(interpolate(generatedText, { variable }));
```

The regular expression `\${([^}]+)}` means:

- `\$` - Literal `$`
- `{` - Literal `{`
- `([^}]+)` First (and only) capture group:

  - `[^}]+` - One or more characters which are not `}`
- `}` - Literal `}`

Since `prop` is the property name found in between the brackets, replace with `obj[prop]` to replace with the desired replacement.

Comment: how you extend your solution to work on `${obj.foo.bar}` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463 - use `reduce` to iterate over the substrings between `.`s to get to the nested value

Comment: @CertainPerformance - You are a hero!

Answer (score 7):

The `interpolate` function below is an extended version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565813/4232558) that adds support for simple nested object field references (e.g.: `a.b.c`)

```js
function interpolate(s, obj) {
  return s.replace(/[$]{([^}]+)}/g, function(_, path) {
    const properties = path.split('.');
    return properties.reduce((prev, curr) => prev && prev[curr], obj);
  })
}

console.log(interpolate('hello ${a.b.c}', {a: {b: {c: 'world'}}}));
// Displays 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 2):

The interpolate function below is an extended version of the above solution adds support for simple nested object field references, with addition of arrays (e.g.: a[0][2].b.c)

```js
const interpolate = (str, obj) => {
  return str.replace(/\${([^}]+)}/g, (_, target) => {
    let keys = target.split(".");
    return keys.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      if (curr.search(/\[/g) > -1) {
        //if element/key in target array is array, get the value and return
        let m_curr = curr.replace(/\]/g, "");
        let arr = m_curr.split("[");
        return arr.reduce((pr, cu) => {
          return pr && pr[cu];
        }, prev);
      } else {
        //else it is a object, get the value and return
        return prev && prev[curr];
      }
    }, obj);
  });
};

let template = "hello ${a[0][0].b.c}";
let data = {
  a: [
    [{
      b: {
        c: "world",
        f: "greetings"
      }
    }, 2], 3
  ],
  d: 12,
  e: 14
}
console.log(interpolate(template, { ...data
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should emulate a template literal instead, because letting text from ~somewhere~ run arbitrary JavaScript like a real template literal’s `${}` sections can usually isn’t a good idea:

```
generatedText.replace(/\$\{variable}/g, variable);
```

Comment: Certain performances answer met my needs a little closer because I could replace multiple instances of different variables in a single pass, but this answer is also correct, does what I was asking and doesn't use eval.