# Render MULTIPLE Template Literals of Multiple Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, str-replace, template-literals

I have the following code above, which came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565813/11332320):

```
const interpolate = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\${([^}]+)}/g,
  (_, prop) => obj[prop]
);

const generatedText = "But I still need to use it as a template it to get ${variable}.";
const variable = "Successs!!!!";

console.log(interpolate(generatedText, { variable }));
```

This perfectly works with ONE variable, but not with multiple variables, which is my intention, like:

```js
const interpolate = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\${([^}]+)}/g,
  (_, prop) => obj[prop]
);

const generatedText = "Hello ${Name}! your Mother ${Mother} is calling you!"; 
const Name = "Ana";
const Mother = "Miley";

console.log(interpolate(generatedText, { Name}, {Mother}));
// Should print: Hello Ana! your Mother Miley is calling you!
```

Which doesn't work.

I've been thinking about using `forEach()` but don't know if I could neither how to use in this case. Read about `map()` but I've only seen this in use to simple replacements like `var resultArr = array.map(function(x){return x.replace(REGULAREXPRESSION, newvalue);});` , which is way different of replacing template literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the second argument you pass to `interpolate` be a *single object* with *multiple properties*. Whenever you want to be able to interpolate something else, add a property to the object (and a `${...}` to the `generatedText` string):

```js
const interpolate = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\${([^}]+)}/g,
  (_, prop) => obj[prop]
);

const generatedText = "Hello ${Name}! your Mother ${Mother} is calling you!"; 
const Name = "Ana";
const Mother = "Miley";

console.log(interpolate(generatedText, { Name, Mother}));
// Should print: Hello Ana! your Mother Miley is calling you!
```