# How to call a function taking parameters in js string template literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

say i have a string like this

```
const myObj = {"far": " bar"}
const s = "hello " + JSON.stringify(myObj)
```

How to convert it to template literal ?

Comment: Please read the documentation: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Comment: What function are you trying to call?  Please show exactly what Javascript you're trying to execute?  The string you show does not show any function or code for a function call.  In general, it's bad form to construct a string in Javascript and then try to execute it.  In general, you already have the function so you just parse the parameters from the string and make a normal function call in regular Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 i thought JSON.stringify() is a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you put any other expression in a template literal, just wrap it in `${}`.

```js
const myObj = {"far": " bar"}
const s = `hello ${JSON.stringify(myObj)}`;
console.log(s);
```