# Resolving text from CLI in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am working on a CLI with typescript and using enquirer to do so. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/enquirer

I have a JSON present.

```
const a = {
   name: 'Mohan',
   age: '5',
};
```

After that I start the Enquirer prompt.

```
Enquirer.prompt({
    name: 'inputVal',
    type: 'input',
    message: 'Create a Text',
  }).then(async response => {
    const output: string = (response as any).inputVal;
    console.log(output);
  });
```

This prompts for the value and I am trying to write this as the answer

```
${a.name} has age ${a.age}
```

This prints on console the following

```
${a.name} has age ${a.age}
```

What I want is for console.log to resolve this as

```
Mohan has age 5
```

I have tried eval as well but it did not work. Does anyone know how can we do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Comment: @MaximMazurok No I tried using eval as stated in post, it does not work.

Comment: does my answer work for you? Can you post the code where you try to use eval otherwise?

Comment: Nope, I just replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182787/4536543) first

```js
const a = {
  name: 'Mohan',
  age: '5',
};
const string = "${a.name} has age ${a.age}";
const templateString = eval('`' + string + '`');
console.log(templateString);
```

Or you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015840/4536543) without `eval()`.

Full example:

```js
const { prompt } = require("enquirer");

const a = {
  name: "Mohan",
  age: "5",
};

prompt({
  name: "inputVal",
  type: "input",
  message: "Create a Text",
}).then(async (response) => {
  const output = response.inputVal;
  const templateString = eval('`' + output + '`');
  console.log(templateString);
});
```

Input:

```
${a.name} has age ${a.age}
```

Produces this output:

```
$ node test.js
√ Create a Text · ${a.name} has age ${a.age}
Mohan has age 5
```

Comment: This is something which works directly, but not when input comes from CLI . Try it yourself,.

Comment: @Prakhar please, see Full example in my updated answer. It really works.

Answer (score 0):

as i see,input is a json and you expect output is `${a.name} has age ${a.age}` ?

try this?

```
Enquirer.prompt({
    name: 'inputVal',
    type: 'input',
    message: 'Create a Text'
}).then(async response => {
    // when you input json string  {"name":"Mohan","age":"5"}
    let a = JSON.parse(response)
    console.log(`${a.name} has age ${a.age}`);
});
```

link to Enquirer api [link](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer)

emm,I am New contributor.if there are some wrong can reply me.thanks

Comment: I tried this, It did not work. Btw, Its a JSON defined as variable as a.

Comment: @ Prakhar   em, i misunderstood. it's a variable.  Maxim Mazurok is right.