# Could not insert data into the template literal for SMS distribution

Tags: javascript, template-literals, template-strings

I have a problem with the template literals JS.
I get user data and an SMS template from a MySQL table.

// User fields

```
let name = data.info.name; // Chingis
let start_datetime = data.info.start_datetime; // 05.07.2020 15:20
let end_time = data.info.end_time; // 16:20
```

// SMS field (text)

```
// From the database
// Text: Dear ${name}! Your contract visit has been approved for ${start_datetime} - ${end_time}. We are waiting for you!
sms_template = data.sms.text;
```

**My insertion**

```
$('#sms-message').text("`" + sms_template + "`");
```

**The result has not changed:**
Dear ${name}! Your contract visit has been approved for ${start_datetime} - ${end_time}. We are waiting for you!

> quote: How to insert variables into a template?

Comment: Check my answer, i have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `eval()` function there to convert that string into template.

so change this:

```
$('#sms-message').text("`" + sms_template + "`");
```

into this:

```
$('#sms-message').text(eval("`" + sms_template + "`"));
```

reference: [Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Comment: Thank you very much! I immediately sent a reply, but it did not reach you. Now I have added an answer and marked it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
$('#sms-message').text("`" + sms_template + "`");
```

with

```
$('#sms-message').text(`${sms_template}`);
```

Comment: Inserted, there is no result

Comment: Can you share the code where you are saving the text to the database?

Comment: Text from DB, varchar(500), manually added to the field. 

`Dear ${name}! Your contract visit has been approved for ${start_datetime} - ${end_time}. We are waiting for you!`

Comment: If I am getting you correctly, you have added this text manually to the database and then you are trying to print this text out by replacing the variables with the declared above in the question?

Comment: Yes. Then to update the text in the "Sms templates" page.

Comment: checkout `eval()` function

Comment: Thank you very much! I immediately sent a reply, but it did not reach you. Now I have added an answer.