# how I convert string into interpolated string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, string

I'm receiving a string from the backend. Let's say

```
"Save Earth, ${name}"
```

At the frontend, I'm using **javascript**
I want to know how can I bind `name` from the variable getting in the string.

I know about the string interpolation in JS like below

```
`Save Earth, ${name}`
```

> Even on using string interpolation is not helping me and
> I'm getting **normal string** from backend like below:

```
  const name = "John"; 
  const response = "Save Earth, ${name}";
  console.log(`${response}`);
```

**What I am getting**

```
"Save Earth, ${name}"
```

**Expected**

```
"Save Earth, John"
```

> **NOTE:** I can't use string **find & replace** method because the variable name can be anything.

**EDIT**:
Do I need to use `Regex` to `find & replace` method only here.

> **Why I am looking for another approach?**
> Because the string can be lengthy and I feel that will increase the time complexity.

Comment: This might also be good to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string. An approach other than find & replace is using `eval`, but that has its own drawbacks.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Yes, I was avoiding `eval` till now. But i'll try to brainstorm little bit on it, if it can be an optimized solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find & replace can stil be used with a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

You could use an object instead of seperate variables with the data you have what to replace. Then inside the replace function you can pass a function as second parameter which returns the correct data.

The reason for an object is that we can't access variables by name (unless you add them to the window object).

```js
const response = "${name} is ${age} years old!";

const data = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: "42"
};

const replaceVariable = (match, inner) => {
  return data[inner] || "";
}

const replaced = response.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/gi, replaceVariable);

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Can't I change whole string into interpolated string? Or the regex is the only option here

Comment: @HarishSharma There are multiple ways, regex is just one. You could add a method to the string prototype ([See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015840/3257622)). Another option is to use `eval()` but it's highly discouraged, so please DON'T use it ([MDN eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)).

Comment: Yes, I was avoiding `eval` for this and I was looking for `time complexity` purpose because the string can be large. I'm accepting `regex` for now. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

For this you need use replace function with regex
With /${\w+}/ variable what have you defined.

```js
const name = "John";
const response = "Save Earth, ${name}";

const newResponse = response.replace(/\${\w+}/ ,name);

console.log(newResponse);
```

Comment: Can't I change whole string into interpolated string? Or the regex is the only option here...

Comment: yes.eval is not recommended to use & discouraged .so regex is the option will work to match the string

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted the answer from @theblackgigant, because he posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you may use `regex` for solving this problem. Get the variable names using `regex` and declare the variables using `var` keyword.

The `var` keyword put the values into `window` object so that your can fetch them from `window`.

You can follow this code-

```js
var name = "John"; 
var email = "hello@example.com";

const response = "Save Earth, ${name} ${email}";

const parse = str => str.replace(/\${(.+?)\}/gm, (match, varName) => window[varName]);

console.log(parse(response));
```