# Typescript: String and String Template relationship - Conversion?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering why I can do this:

```
let stT: `${number}%` = "5435%"
```

But not this:

```
let str: string = "5435%"
let strT: `${number}%` = str;
```

And also not this:

```
let str: string = 5435
let strT: `${number}%` = `${str}%`;
```

What is the relationship (if any) of string and string template? Why can I assign a template a litteral but not a string variable?
Is there a way you can match and convert the string to a string template?

I found this:
[Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)
But I believe it to slightly different than my question.

Comment: In the second case str's inferred type is just string, surely; there's absolutely no guarantee it will be a string *ending with %*.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the type of str. Edit includes them now. Is there a way to match it similar to regex.match() or convert the string to the template?

Comment: And now in the third case the compiler errors out on the obvious mismatch between `5435` and the explicit type of `string` before reaching the string templating part.

Comment: In the third case, if you replace `let str: string` with `let str: number`, it still doesn't work. However, this was [fixed in the 4.2 beta](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2-beta/#template-literal-expressions-have-template-literal-types).

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's not true. Check out [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYGVgCcCWA7AcygF4oADAEgG885UAjCLAXwrIG4BYAKB4GNkeJFFQgAYnDx8SUABQA3AIYAbAFyxEKDNnwEAlCQB8UKjyhQsEYHCx4oS5V27MePURKmyA5AAYAjABMAMwUXnpO7pJ83v7BwQAswWER4lHeogByEADumLiEyUA). I set it up so that only Template Literal Types can be applied to the function that and on `$`

Comment: @DivisionByZero *what's* not true? That the inferred type in case 2 prior to the edit was `string`, or that the value `5435` isn't assignable to a variable with the explicit type `string` in case 3 afterwards?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm sorry. I think I completely misunderstood your first comment. I thought you were referring to the type declaration in the first example.