# How to put variable value in another variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an sql statement, which should contain variable value in it.
but because the sql statement is coming from database retrieve, I cant do this.

my code is:

```
    var MySQLCommand_101 = `
        SELECT PARAM_VALUE FROM MNG.GENERAL.MNG_ELT_PARAMETERS
    `;
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(  {sqlText:MySQLCommand_101}  );
    var resultSet = stmt.execute();
    resultSet.next();
    var VALIDATION_RESULT = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
```

now,

```
VALIDATION_RESULT = 'CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > ${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT'
```

in my code, I assigned ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD = 30.
but because the VALIDATION_RESULT  is coming in the execution dinamically, and did not compiled- when I return VALIDATION_RESULT I get the string itself,

```
CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > ${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT
```

while I'm expecting to get

```
CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT
```

thanks for helping,

Comment: did you try with VALIDATION_RESULT = ' ... \`${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD}\` ' with reverse apex (ALT+96) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182244/convert-a-string-to-a-template-string)

Comment: @DonDiego did not anderstand what you ment.

Comment: @DonDiego, your suggestion return CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > ``${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD}`` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have "CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT" as VALIDATION_RESULT, you can replace the variable after fetching the value:

```
var ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD = 30;
var MySQLCommand_101 = `
    SELECT PARAM_VALUE FROM MNG.GENERAL.MNG_ELT_PARAMETERS
`;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(  {sqlText:MySQLCommand_101}  );
var resultSet = stmt.execute();
resultSet.next();
var VALIDATION_RESULT_TMP = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
var VALIDATION_RESULT = VALIDATION_RESULT_TMP.replace("${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD}",ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD ));
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code

`VALIDATION_RESULT = 'CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > ${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT'`

replace the single quotes (`' '`) with  `` ` ` ``.

```
VALIDATION_RESULT = `CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > ${ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT`
```

Comment: I cant insert this to my database.
INSERT INTO MNG_ELT_PARAMETERS VALUES
(concat(`CASE WHEN DIV0(ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS) * 100 > $`,`{ERROR_PERCENTAGE_THRESHOLD}` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALIDATION_RESULT`)
I have to use concat because the ${}, and then the `` dont allow me to put *