# Display \n and \r\n characters in Dev Tools of a browser

Tags: javascript, ascii

In JavaScript, I have strings including newlines such as `var s = "123\n456"` or `var s = "123\r\n456"`.

Using `console.log(s)`, the dev tools of a browser displays real newlines in console.

I would like to know how to print literally the string. For instance, I want to see `123\n456` or `123\r\n456` in dev tools or a browser.

Could anyone help?

Comment: What console is showing them literally? Most browser consoles show a string-literal-like display (that is, with `\n` in it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could `console.log(JSON.stringify(s))`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily display the raw string using String.raw and a template literal

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

```js
const rawString = String.raw`Hello\nHow do you do?`;
console.log(rawString);
```

If you can not directly use a template literal, you can [convert the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182787/7978627) into a template literal, and then proceed. Note my linked method includes eval which can be a security risk depending on use.

i.e.

```js
const myString = "Hello\nWorld";
const myRawString = eval("String.raw`"+myString+"`");
```

Comment: The OP has a string, not a template literal. You've shown them how to do this with a template literal instead.

Comment: updated with converting string to template literal 

Comment: This is not what the OP wants 
OP has strings with actual newlines, that he wants to be shown as C style escape sequences in the console

Comment: Your update will result in `myString === myRawString` being `true` (assuming it doesn't fail because the string has `"` in it), so that doesn't help. ```const myString = "123\n456"; const myRawString = eval("String.raw`"+myString+"`"); console.log(myRawString === myString);``` (Shows `true`) There may well be a `String.raw` way to do this, but this isn't it, and `JSON.stringify` works well, so... :-)