# How do I changes node labels?

Tags: neo4j, sigma.js, linkurious

I have a little Neo graph:

```
match (f) optional match (f)-[r]-() delete f, r;
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-1', System: 'UNK' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-2', System: 'Oracle GL' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'X&X', System: 'Classic' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-3', System: 'Classic' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-4', System: 'Sun System' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-5', System: 'Oracle GL' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-6', System: 'Oracle GL' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-7', System: 'Direct (No Interface)' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
```

for which I'm trying to produce a graph where the nodes use the data property (node attribute in Neo) 'System', but I can't get it work.  here's the code:

```
var neo = {
    url: 'http://localhost:7474',
    user: 'neo4j',
    password: '***'
};      
sigma.neo4j.cypher(neo,
    'MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m LIMIT 100',
    { container: 'graph' },
    function (s) { 
        sigma.plugins.killDesign(s);
        var design = sigma.plugins.design(s);
        design.setStyles({
            nodes: {
                label: { by: 'neo4j_data.System' }
            }   
        });         
        design.apply();
    }       
);
```

you'll note that unlike the sample references in the documentation which *data.something*, I use *neo4j_data.something* as I've found from debugging that for graphs retrieved from Neo4j, that's where node attributes seem to reside.

apparently the place where this data should be accessed is in the `applyStyle` method defined in `sigma.plugins.design.js`, specifically line 534, which I quote below:

```
if (!(visualVar in self.originalVisualVariable[item.id])) {
  // non-writable property
  Object.defineProperty(self.originalVisualVariable[item.id], visualVar, {
   enumerable: true,
   value: item[visualVar]
  });
}
```

where it may be seen that the value of the label (visualVar is currently set to "label") gets set to `item[visualVar]`... however `item` contains:

```
{
Object
cam0:size: 8
cam0:x: 656.8832126805254
cam0:y: 191.29239469613498
color: "#000000"
id: "0"
label: "0"
neo4j_data: {
    Org: "UNK-1"
    System: "UNK"
}
neo4j_labels: Array[1]
read_cam0:size: 8
read_cam0:x: 61.38321268052541
read_cam0:y: 91.79239469613499
size: 1
x: 0.8536414597183466
y: 0.980357211548835
__proto__: Object
}
```

from which can be seen that though there is an attribute `item.label`, what it should really do is retrieve `item.neo4j_data.System`.

am I misunderstanding this, or how is it supposed to work?

TIA - e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong about the code that pulls node attributes.  later on there is this fragment:

```
var newVal = o.styles[visualVar](item);
```

which refers to this (in the `update` method):

```
case 'label':
  self.idx[key][val].styles.label = function(item) {
    return format(byFn(item, key));
  };
  break;
```

where:

```
format = that.mappings.label.format || function(item) {
              return item.label;
            };
byFn: function(item, key) { return strToObjectRef(item, key); };

function strToObjectRef(obj, str) {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6393943
  return str.split('.').reduce(function(obj, i) { return obj[i] }, obj);
}
```

...in looking at the output of `byFn` we find it's not an object, it's a string! so the dereference in the default `format` method fails.

so declaring my style like this makes it work:

```
design.setStyles({
    nodes: {
        label: {
            by: 'neo4j_data.System',
            format: function(item) { return item; }
        }
    }   
});
```

so the lesson here is that the `format` method is required when working with Neo4j

*** Update I ***

a patch to the code to redefine the `format` method would fix this problem:

```
format = that.mappings.label.format || function(item) {
              return typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.label;
            };
```