# string to object conversion (dot format)

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, javascript-objects

I have a string `cars.type.suv` and I'm trying to access the object props but the object is a string.

```
var cars = {
   type:{
      suv:{
        //watever
      }
   }
};
```

Question: How can I turn the string `cars.type.suv` into the object.

Comment: I imagine: `var cars = {type:{suv:"this is a string, isn't it?"}};` now... what format is the string in?

Comment: do you want to convert the string into an object with nested levels?

Comment: @apsillers no simply just the string `cars.type.suv`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest exactly I can't access them, if there was only one level I could just use brackets but there is multiple

Comment: This might insterest you: [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

Comment: @SparK no it's object properties whatever they may be, its just accessing multiple nested when only having a string.

Comment: @JordanDavis You want to create the object?! split the string by `.` and iterate, checking if the prop is defined in a container so you create objects on your way down and in the last node you set the node name as value too.

Comment: I think that duplicate answers your question. Let me know if I misunderstood your question, and maybe edit it to clarify and then I can reopen it if you want.

Comment: @blex yea I already read that one

Comment: so, the last element like `.suv` should always be an object, or it sometimes may be an object property?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest doesn't matter what object above is simply in example, it's being able to turn a string which is `my.obj.somewhere.with.whatever.nested.levels`

Comment: @SparK the object is already created I'm simply trying to access the properties.

Comment: This works like a charm for me: `<script>
var cars = {
   type:{
      suv:{
        name: "HI"
      }
   }
};

document.write(cars.type.suv.name);
</script>
`

Comment: @pid thats not a string... I think everyone knows how to access the the object the way you just listed, you have to realize it's a string `cars.type.suv`

Comment: @JordanDavis To be clear: the duplicate answers you question, right? If not, [edit] your question and explain how it does not. Also, this might be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Comment: @apsillers I just tried it and its good, thanks guys!

Comment: Now I understand... you have to split the string at the `.` and then recursively navigate the object tree. That's easy to do but it cannot be written in a comment.