# Checking existence of nested property in an object javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nested

I have already reviewed some of the answers to similar questions, however, I want to ask my question differently.

Let's say we have a string like **"level1.level2.level3. ..."** that indicates a nested property in an object called **Obj**.

The point is that we *may not* know how many nested properties exist in this string. For instance, it may be "level1.level2" or "level1.level2.level3.level4".

Now, I want to write a function, that given the **Obj** and the string of properties as input, to simply tell us if such a nested property exists in the object or not (let's say true or false as output).

---

Update:
Thanks to @Silvinus, I found the solution with a minor modification:

```
        private checkNestedProperty(obj, props) {
        var splitted = props.split('.');
        var temp = obj;
        for (var index in splitted) {
            if (temp[splitted[index]] === 'undefined' || !temp[splitted[index]]) return false;
            temp = temp[splitted[index]];
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @Pedram, you want to get "report" about existence of each property or just for the most(last) nested one?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest In fact, the most (last) one. However, it is obvious that if each of these properties does not exist, the last one does not exist as well :)

Comment: I am wondering why my question should get a down vote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explore your Obj with this function :

```
var fn = function(obj, props) {
        var splited = props.split('.');
        var temp = obj;
        for(var index in splited) {
            if(typeof temp[splited[index]] === 'undefined') return false;
            temp = temp[splited[index]]
        }
           return true
        }

var result = fn({ }, "toto.tata");
console.log(result); // false

var result = fn({ toto: { tata: 17 } }, "toto.tata");
console.log(result); // true

var result = fn({ toto: { tata: { tutu: 17 } } }, "toto.foo.tata");
console.log(result); // false
```

This function allow to explore nested property of Obj that depends of props passed in parameter

Comment: This answer fails on the case `fn({a:false}, 'a')`. Minor point, but there is no need for the variable `temp` here.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `temp = temp[splited[index]];`? For that reason, the test case `fn({a: {b: { c: 1 }}}, 'a.b.c')` causes a run-time error "Cannot read property 'c' of undefined".

Comment: For the first comment, ... I agree. I write this code so fast. I edited it and change my test by 
if(typeof temp[splited[index]] === 'undefined') return false;

For the second, sorry it's a mistake. 
temp = obj[splited[index]] must be replace by temp = temp[splited[index]]

Comment: @Silvinus Thank you, I have modified your answer (minor mistake) and put the correct function in my update.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and `thisArg` of it, by iterating the keys and checking if it is in the given object.

```js
var fn = function (o, props) {
    return props.split('.').every(k => k in o && (o = o[k], true));
}

console.log(fn({}, "toto.tata"));                                   // false
console.log(fn({ toto: { tata: 17 } }, "toto.tata"));               // true
console.log(fn({ toto: { tata: { tutu: 17 } } }, "toto.foo.tata")); // false
console.log(fn({ toto: { tata: false } }, "toto.tata")); // true
```

Comment: does not work if value of a key is falsy, or null. 
`console.log(fn({ toto: { tata: false } }, "toto.tata")); // false`

Comment: @MorloMbakop, thank you for the hint. now it should work as expected. please see edit.

Comment: Looks lovely like  ost of your answers, although i don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference) provides the basic answer to your question. But it needs to be tweaked to handle the undefined case:

```
function isDefined(obj, path) {
  function index(obj, i) { 
    return obj && typeof obj === 'object' ? obj[i] : undefined; 
  }

  return path.split(".").reduce(index, obj) !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: why downvote? downvoter, how about some explanation?! Or, maybe, you're just clicking without arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution given by @Silvinus here is a solution if you deal with array inside nested objects (as it is often the case in results from databases queries) :

```
checkNested = function(obj, props) {
    var splited = props.split('.');
    var temp = obj;
    for(var index in splited) {
      var regExp = /\[([^)]+)\]/;
      var matches = regExp.exec(splited[index])
      if(matches) {
        splited[index] = splited[index].replace(matches[0], '');
      }
      if(matches) {
        if(matches && typeof temp[splited[index]][matches[1]] === 'undefined') return false;
            temp = temp[splited[index]][matches[1]];
      }
      else {
            if(!matches && typeof temp[splited[index]] === 'undefined') return false;
                temp = temp[splited[index]]
      }
    }
    return true
}

obj = {ok: {ao: [{},{ok: { aa: ''}}]}}

console.log(checkNested(obj, 'ok.ao[1].ok.aa')) // ==> true
console.log(checkNested(obj, 'ok.ao[0].ok.aa')) // ==> false
```