# angular2 form validator by pressing enter

Tags: forms, angular, submit, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a form submitted by pressing enter. but when I press enter , the form is submitted but the validators are not run

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form"  (keyup.enter)="updateApplicationLink()">
   <input  [(ngModel)]="table.labelFR"   ngControl="labelfr">

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form= fb.group({
      labelfr: new Control('', Validators.required)
  });
```

Comment: works fine, i log validation state of form and it's as expected. `updateApplicationLink(){
    console.log(this.form.valid)
  }`

Comment: ngModel can binds to component property only. maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583909/angular2-bind-ngmodel-to-a-reference-of-a-property/37583928#37583928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for required validation:

```
<input ng-model="labelFR" required>
<h1>{{form.labelFR.$valid}}</h1>
```

Comment: `ng-model` ? it's `Angular2`