# Add new entry to (empty) scope array using ng-click directive

Tags: arrays, angularjs, push

My scope does not contain an "notYetExistingArray" at the time of generation.

Via a button, I would like to add the array plus a first entry to it.
Each subsequent push of the same button should then add another entry.

Unfortunately, I have no clue on how to approach it.

Currently I have:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="notYetExistingArray.unshift({})">
```

If the scope already contains an object "notYetExistingArray" of type array = [] I can easily add an entry with above function.

Any advise on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Call a controller function from your `ng-click` directive rather than trying to do all that stuff in your markup. It can include a check for the existence of the array, and create it if needed.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addThis(thing)">
```

In the controller:

```
ctrl.addThis = function(thing) {
    if (ctrl.myArray === undefined) {
        ctrl.myArray = [];
    }

    myArray.unshift(thing);
};
```

Note that I'm using [controllerAs](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax here, so `ctrl` might be `$scope` instead.

Comment: This works. Any hint on how I can also define myArray as parameter to the addThis function?

Comment: Do you mean a property or a function argument?

Comment: Basically I want to pass the object property to be used as un-initialized array within the scope to the function as well. So function addThis("prop1.prop2", {}) should add {} to a potentially not existing scope-entry such as scope.prop1.prop2 - I am not a Javascript expert, so it is hard to explain

Comment: I have found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference but it seems as I am simply not able to convert that logic to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array before doing that, for example:

```
<button type="button" ng-init="notYetExistingArray=[]" ng-click="notYetExistingArray.unshift({})">
```

check the documentation for ng-init https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: This is ok until such time as the array exists on scope at page load. Maybe better to check for its existence rather than assuming.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to bind a function on the `ngClick` directive, which will perform a test in order to check if the array exist.

In your **controller** :

```
function foo(item) {
  //if my array does not exist
  if (!$scope.myArray) {
    //create the array
    $scope.myArray = [];
  }
  //Here, we can add some data to our array, we are sure that the array exist
  $scope.myArray.unshift(item);
}

$scope.foo = foo;
```

**Html** :

```
<h2>Array.length : {{myArray.length}}</h2>
</br>
<button type="button" ng-click="foo({})">Add</button>
```

Feel free to check the [**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TRzWZhs2efU4kZEDbTpg?p=preview)