# Javascript apply() not working with var in bracket notation

Tags: javascript, apply

I want to invoke a function using apply(), but when I pass a var with bracket notation, it does not work any more. Why this does not work? thanks

`window.video['play'] = OK
window.video.play = OK
obj[p[i]] = not OK <= something like this I'd like to use`

```
var obj = window;
var prop = 'video.play';

var p = prop.split('.');
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[p[i]];
}

var orig = obj; // problem here with obj: window.video['play'] = OK, but obj[p[i]] = not OK
obj = function() {
    var ar = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(ar); // not work!
    orig.apply(this, ar);
};
```

almost the same, but this works:

```
var orig = window.video.play;
window.video.play = function() {
    var ar = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(ar); // work!
    orig.apply(this, ar);
};
```

Comment: You override the `obj` variable: `obj = obj[p[i]];`

Comment: @Dekel: That seems to be the right thing to do.

Comment: What exactly does `console.log(ar); // not work!` mean?

Comment: How do you call `obj`? Why do you reassign your variables in a so confusing way?

Comment: You need to explain what you expect, what you get and any error messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Comment: Thx all @epascarello the link looks good thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tld;dr:** If you want to change the value of `video.play`, then **you have to explicitly assign to it**. Only because `obj` has the same value as `video.play` doesn't mean that assigning to `obj` will change the value of `video.play`.

---

`obj` is a variable. Assigning a new value to a variable does not magically assign the new value to another variable or property. Lets get some ASCII art.

Lets start with

```
var foo = {
  fn: function() {
    console.log(foo);
  },
};
```

This creates the following object structure in memory:

```
                         +--------------+                     
+----+-----------+       |  Object#123  |                     
|foo |  ref:123 *+------>+------+-------+     +--------------+
+----+-----------+       | fn   |   *---+---->| Function#456 |
                         +------+-------+     +--------------+
```

If we assign the function to another variable, e.g.

```
var bar = foo.fn;
```

then `bar` directly points to the function object.

```
                        +--------------+                      
                        |  Object#123  |                      
                    +--->------+-------+      +--------------+
                    |   | fn   |    *--+----->| Function#456 |
+----+-----------+  |   +------+-------+      +--------------+
|foo |  ref:123 *+--+                                 ^       
+----+-----------+                                    |       
|bar |  ref:456 *+------------------------------------+       
+----+-----------+
```

Now, assigning a **new** value `bar` will do just that: It will make `bar` point to another value, but it won't have any impact on `foo` or `foo.fn`:

```
bar = function() {
  console.log('bar');
};
```

As you can see, `foo.fn` still points to the original function:

```
                         +--------------+                     
                         |  Object#123  |                     
                    +--->+------+-------+     +--------------+
                    |    | fn   |   *---+---->| Function#456 |
+----+-----------+  |    +------+-------+     +--------------+
|foo |  ref:123 *+--+                                         
+----+-----------+       +--------------+                     
|bar |  ref:789 *+------>| Function#789 |                     
+----+-----------+       +--------------+
```

Comment: Very good explanation of the problem. If I may add a simple solution to this for this particular question, you can correctly overwrite the `video.play` function by continuously storing the last parent object in the hierarchy using `parent = obj;` in the loop that gets the function reference, then overwrite it using `parent[p[p.length - 1]] = ...`. Though it really feels like there are some odd design choices that took us to this place.

Comment: I had the feeling the probem could be sth. to do with the pointer or overwriting, but was not sure untill this explaination. Thor84no, thx for your suggestion, i will try it...

Comment: @dmj16: It doesn't actually have anything to do with "pointers" (references is a better word). You can simplify the issue to `var foo = 42; var bar = foo;`. Assigning a new value to `bar` (`bar = 21;`) won't change the value of `foo`. The keywords to look for are *pass-by-value* (which is what JavaScript does) vs *pass-by-reference* (not to confuse with object references). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy .