# Check if Key Value exists in JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I want to know if the key-value pair exists in JSON data while retrieving data.
Display "NA" inside div element if not present or else display the value of that key.

HTML:

```
   <div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
     $.get('http://api.fixer.io/2000-02-03',function(person){
         if(person.hasOwnProperty('rates.BGN'))  {
              $('#output').text(person.rates.BGN);
            }
         else  {
              $('#output').text('NA');
              }
          });
```

Comment: What precisely is the problem?

Comment: parse `json` to javascript object then `hasOwnProperty ` will work.
`var res = JSON.parse(person);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to parse person into JSON.

Secondly you are misusing hasOwnProperty, it cannot be used to drill down into an object more than one level the way you are trying.

Finally hasOwnProperty is just unnecessary -- just test for existence as follows:

```
 $.get('http://api.fixer.io/2000-02-03',function(person){
     person = JSON.parse(person); 
     if(person.rates.BGN !== undefined)  {
          $('#output').text(person.rates.BGN);
     }
     //etc.
```

Comment: no need to parse if you use dataType argument or just use `$.getJSON`