# Update Object value with String Dot Notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function filterResult(field, value){
    var result = [
        {
            "name": "Johnson",
            "age": "12",
            "interests": {
                "color": "red"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Calvin",
            "age": "24",
            "interests": {
                "color": "blue"
            }
        }
    ];
    var filter = $.map(result, function(n, i){
        //other stuff here...
        n[field] = value; //dot notation
        return n;
    });
    return filter;
}

filterResult("interests.color","black");
```

Is there a way to convert String Dot Notation **"interests.color"** to object **"n[field]"** to update the value?

- Please note **"interests.color"** just an example. sometimes level can be deeper e.g. **"interests.car.make.year"**. Dynamic is an idea.

*Got an answer from other post.*

```
function setterDotNotation(obj, str, value){
    if (typeof str == 'string'){
        return setterDotNotation(obj,str.split('.'), value);
    }else if (str.length==1 && value!==undefined){
        return obj[str[0]] = value;
    }else if (str.length==0){
        return obj;
    }else{
        return setterDotNotation(obj[str[0]], str.slice(1), value);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also this other post  ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Answer (score 2):

You're not dealing with JSON here, you're dealing with an object (more specifically, an array of objects).

Anyway, you can `.split()` the `"interests.color"` string on the `"."` and then use the two pieces:

```
var fieldNames = field.split(".");       // returns ["interests", "color"]
n[fieldNames[0]][fieldNames[1]] = value;
```

Expand and run the following snippet to see it work in context:

```js
function filterResult(field, value){
    var result = [
        {
            "name": "Johnson",
            "age": "12",
            "interests": {
                "color": "red"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Calvin",
            "age": "24",
            "interests": {
                "color": "blue"
            }
        }
    ];
    var filter = $.map(result, function(n, i){
        //other stuff here...
            var fieldNames = field.split(".");
            n[fieldNames[0]][fieldNames[1]] = value;
            return n;
    });
    return filter;
}

console.log( filterResult("interests.color","black") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I agree, but this does not help with any object sent to this function that is in the 3rd layer or below. However acceptable for the current requirement I guess

Comment: @bureaquete - Well sure, but deeper nesting is still just a matter of splitting and then adding a loop to navigate down through the object one layer at a time, i.e., just the next logical step beyond what I've shown.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for the answer. But this is just a sample with "interests.color". sometimes can be more deeper. e.g. "interests.car.make.year". I wish i can make it more dynamic instead of hardcoded the level.