# Javascript JSON group child properties name

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a string which contains multiple properties and sub-properties, which I would like to convert to a JSON object. The string I currently have is of this format:

```
"{"menuId":"1","menuItemDetails.itemDetailsId":"4","menuItemDetails.itemType.itemTypeId":"4","accessGroups":"","menuItemDetails.name":"","menuItemDetails.route":"","menuItemDetails.displayRule":"","menuItemDetails.continueMode":"","menuItemDetails.isSilent":"0","menuItemDetails.message.messageId":"26","menuItemDetails.title.messageId":"","menuItemDetails.defaultMessage.messageId":"","menuItemDetails.onSelect.messageId":"","menuItemDetails.action.actionId":"2","menuItemDetails.action.actionTypeId":"2","menuItemDetails.action.name":"GenerateViewMembersAction","menuItemDetails.action.fullyQualifiedName":"test.actions.sharedplans.GenerateViewMembersAction","menuItemDetails.action.plugin.pluginId":"1"}"
```

If I do a normal JSON.parse, I get an object like the following:

```
accessGroups
:
""
menuId
:
"1"
menuItemDetails.action.actionId
:
"2"
menuItemDetails.action.actionTypeId
:
"2"
menuItemDetails.action.fullyQualifiedName
:
"test.GenerateViewMembersAction"
menuItemDetails.action.name
:
"GenerateViewMembersAction"
```

I would like to group by propreties name, so I get the following:

```
{
 menuId: 1
,menuItemDetails: {
  action: {
     actionId: 1
    ,actionTypeId: 2
    ...
   }
,name: "GenerateView..."
 }
}
```

Anyone can help me figure this out?

**EDIT**: To put things more into perspective, the case I have is a list of HTML elements, each having a name and a value, from which I want to build the JSON object. That does give me control over the JSON string, or allows me to create a JSON object directly if needed.

Comment: Your input is in JSON format so `JSON.parse` is going to read every key-value pair delimited by commas and assign those properties and values to an object. You have properties like `menuItemDetails.itemDetailsId`, which will be the literal name of the property, not create an inner `menuItemDetails` object. JSON supports nested objects, can't you rewrite your input?

Comment: If changing whatever builds the string is an option, that's the way to go here, otherwise, you're looking at this question, which seems similar:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the JSON parser as is, since it simply treats `"menuItemDetails.itemDetailsId"` as a monolithic identifier. After all, how should it know that this actually depicts a nested object.

You either have to write your own parser that reads the string and creates the object structure taking your special circumstances into account. This however is a quite cumbersome task (if you want to do it properly).

I would go with a two-step approach. First use the built-in JSON parser to create a regular object. Then, iterate over your object properties and simply split all the properties containing a `.` and combine them into new nested objects. You can use regular code for copying objects ([which is not trivial as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)) and then add your special rule to split the keys containing a `.` accordingly.

Splitting an object path could be done like following (this however does not account for duplicate paths!):

```js
obj = {"test.foo.bar.baz":"value","one.two":"anothervalue"};
var out = {};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(
   (e)=> e[0].split(".")
             .reduceRight(function(acc, val,i) {
                 return (i==0) ? out[val] = acc : {[val] : acc};
             }, e[1])
);

console.log(out);
```

If you have control over it, the easiest thing is prabobly to correct the input string in the first place.