# JSX How to add object values into String that might be null or undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Here is my exact code:

```
   <Text style={styles.priceText} numberOfLines={2}>
          {'$ '+item.right.detail ? item.right.detail.price: ''}{'\n'}{'\n'}
   </Text>
```

So sometimes it's possible that item.right.detail is null or perhaps undefined.  This check is not working. I get an error undefined is not an object (evaluating item.right.detail)

I need a way to be able to construct strings of data from object elements where some of those sub objects or values could be null. Obviously I want to do this without crashing!

Do I have to do something crazy like:

```
  private getPrice(item){
      var retVal = '$';
      if (typeof item !== 'undefined' ) && (item)) {
         if (typeof item.right !== 'undefined' ) && (item.right)) {
          if (typeof item.right.detail !== 'undefined' ) &&  (item.right.detail)) {

           if (typeof item.right.detail.price !== 'undefined' ) && (item.right.detail.price)) {
              retVal = retVal+item.right.detail.price;
          }  
       }    
    }
 }
 return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Try AND condition : {'$ '+ item.right && item.right.detail ? item.right.detail.price: ''}{'\n'}{'\n'}

Comment: I think it will still crash if item.right is undefined. But I will try it.

Comment: No It will not crash. If Item is undefined than It will crash.

Comment: Ok now I tried:  {'฿ '+ item.right && item.right.detail ? item.right.detail.price: ''}{'\n'}{'\n'} but I get 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.right.detail') So I need to check both item.right and item.right.detail are both not undefined. Not sure how to nest this check.

Comment: Use lodash as outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Answer (score 0):

Try using !! operator. For null values, !! returns false, so, your code could be something like this:

```
<Text style={styles.priceText} numberOfLines={2}>
      {'$ '+ (!item || !item.right || !item.right.detail || !item.right.detail.price) ? '' : item.right.detail.price}{'\n'}{'\n'}
</Text>
```

Comment: if `item.right` is undefined, then this will not work anyway, because we can't take .detail out of undefined...

Comment: I will try it.  However, I think this is probably a place for lodash library which is probably implemented very similar to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can best be solved by lodash library.

see https://lodash.com/docs#get
_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])

Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.

_.get(item, "item.right.detail.price", 'Not available')  // This should work.