# create key to access item in object with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have the below object where I want to get the name of the first item in the staff array.

```
const staffObj = {
  "staff":[
    { "name": "tom"},
    { "name": "sam"}
  ]
}
```

I can do this by doing either

```
console.log(staffObj['staff'][0]['name'])
console.log(staffObj.staff[0].name)
```

But what I want to do is is access my object from a variable I create
eg

```
const currentField = 'name'    
const firstITem = ['staff'][currentField ]
console.log(firstITem,staffObj.firstITem)
```

What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe have a look at  [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/218196)

Comment: That's not possible (unless you implement a getter or proxy on the object)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put bits of Javascript source code in a variable like that. You need variables for each part:

```
const currentType = 'staff';
const currentField = 'name';
console.log(staffObj[currentType][0][currentField]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missing `[0]` in your code. You should use a function for such things. Example:

```
function firstFtaffField(staffObj, field) {
  return staffObj['staff'][0][field];
}

// Usage
var name = firstFtaffField(staffObj, 'name');
```

Comment: +1                                                                                                 for "use a function".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to use `currentField` as a variable. Notice how `firstITem[currentField]` has `currentField` which is not in quotes. It is a variable and evaluated by javascript and then applied as property `name`.

```js
const staffObj = {
  "staff":[
    { "name": "tom"},
    { "name": "sam"}
  ]
};

console.log(staffObj['staff'][0]['name']);
console.log(staffObj.staff[0].name)

const currentField = 'name';   
const firstITem = staffObj.staff[0];
console.log(firstITem[currentField]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, but you could do something similar by defining `firstItem` as a function:

```js
const staffObj = {
  "staff":[
    { "name": "tom"},
    { "name": "sam"}
  ]
};

const currentField = 'name';
const firstItem = x => x['staff'][0][currentField];
console.log(firstItem(staffObj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You look like you might want something like function!

As a quick note since you seem to be a beginner: [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var get = n => c => c[n]; // function given a nest returns a function given a container returns the nest inside the container
var obj = {
  staff:[
    { name: 'tom' },
    { name: 'sam' }
  ]
};

var getFirst = get(0);
var getStaff = get('staff');

console.log(getFirst(getStaff(obj))); // { name: 'tom }
```

Of course this is functional programming that relys on composition, so if that doesn't make too much send to you you can instead go with a more familiar imperative version:

```
var obj = { staff: [ {name:'tom'}, {name:'sam'}]};
var getStaff = obj => obj['staff'];
var getFirst = ary => ary[0];

var staff = getStaff(obj);
var firstStaff = getFirst(staff);

// alternate
//var getFirstStaff = obj => getFirst(getStaff(obj));

console.log(firstStaff);
```

As you can see there are some similarities between the two, but composition is done in a reversed order with some more advanced techniques(composition, currying). Since you seem to be new to JS I'd suggest doing it the second way so it makes more sense until you understand the first way(which will make thinking in promises a LOT easier)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the `someObject.someProperty` notation is a shorthand for `someObject['someProperty']`.

Which means that if you want to have a dynamically calculated property name, you can't use a 'dot' notation, because `someObject.someProperty` will always be interpreted as `someObject['someProperty']` regardless of the fact that `someProperty` is maybe a valid variable which holds some value of string type.

Also, if you try to use something like `someObject."someProperty"` you will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`, because that isn't a valid JS syntax.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such syntax. The only way you could do it using eval:

```
const staffObj = {
  "staff":[
    { "name": "tom"},
    { "name": "sam"}
  ]
};
const currentField = 'name';
const firstItem = ".staff[0]." + currentField;
console.log(eval("staffObj" + firstItem));
```

If `currentField` is actually variable, then you will have to change `firstItem` as well every time you change the `currentField`.

Comment: This is what `eval` should **not** be used for.

Comment: @Bergi, according to global warming eval should not be used at all. This is the only solution that can answer the question if firstItem is actually a dynamic variable, which I believe is true due to the question itself. Quote "access my object from a **variable** I create"

Comment: No, this is [not the only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394168/1048572).