# Setting a deep JS object key using a lookup string

Tags: javascript, object

How do I set deep properties in a JavaScript object using a dot-syntax string to specify which property I want to change?

For simple objects, I could just use `data['property_name'] = 'foo'`, but I don't necessarily know how deeply nested the data is going to be.

Below is some example code with how I'd like to be able to format the data in the end. For all I know there's a nice way that JS already allows you to do this, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

[Plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/KAFb7JNGoCv2FZFWteaJ?p=preview)

```
var items = [
    {
        lookup_string: "User.UserProfile.name",
        value: "John Smith"
    },
    {
        lookup_string: "User.email",
        value: "johnsmith@example.com"
    },
]



var data = {};

items.forEach(function(item){
    // Inside this loop, set the appropriate keys under data. Is there a non-convoluted way to do this?
});

console.log("items", items);
console.log("Results", data)

// In the end, data should look like this:

var desiredData = {
    User: {
        UserProfile: {
            name: 'John Smith'
        },
        email: 'johnsmith@example.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you're going to have to manually assign the values by looping over `lookup_string.split('.')`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the `lookup_string` and reduce an object with a default object. Later assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var keys = path.split('.'),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var items = [{ lookup_string: "User.UserProfile.name", value: "John Smith" }, { lookup_string: "User.email", value: "johnsmith@example.com" }],
    object = {};

items.forEach(function(o) {
    setValue(object, o.lookup_string, o.value);
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to loop over all the keys from lookup_string.split('.') and assign values, something like this:

```
  var items = [
        {
            lookup_string: "User.UserProfile.name",
            value: "John Smith"
        },
        {
            lookup_string: "User.email",
            value: "johnsmith@example.com"
        },
    ];

    var data = {};

    items.forEach(function(item){
       var lookup = item.lookup_string.split('.');
       var lastKey;
       lookup.map(function(key){
            data[key] = {};
            lastKey = key;
       });
       data[lastKey] = item.value;
    });

    console.log("items", items);
    console.log("Results", data)

    // In the end, data should look like this:

    var desiredData = {
        User: {
            UserProfile: {
                name: 'John Smith'
            },
            email: 'johnsmith@example.com'
        }
    };
```