# How to get proprety value of object from parent object

Tags: javascript

I have object in this structure:

```
obj = {
    user: { name: 'jeterson' },
    title: 'I am a test'
}
```

I have one key with value: `user.name`.
I have trying get value like this: `obj[key]`, meaning `obj['user.name']`. It not works, only works for `obj.title`.

My object have many values that are also objects, and i want get value like this:

```
myobject[mykey]
```

It is possible get value from property object  like above ?

Comment: You don't even need brakets and qoutes just use dot notation `obj.user.name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got multiple solutions to access an element of an object with its keys:

```js
var obj = {
  user: { name: 'jeterson' },
  title: 'I am a test'
}

console.log(obj['user']['name']);
console.log(obj['user'].name);
console.log(obj.user['name']);
console.log(obj.user.name);
```

But you can't do it easily with a variable `key = 'user.name'`.

If you need to use a variable containing the nested-keys, you could create a function.

**Updated answer:** An amazingly short way to achieve it is to use `.reduce()`:

```js
// My function
function obj_tree_key(obj, path) {
 return path.split('.').reduce((accu, val) => accu[val] || 'Not found', obj);
}

var obj1 = {
  user: {
    name: 'jeterson'
  },
  title: 'I am a test'
}
console.log(obj_tree_key(obj1, 'user.name')); // Outputs "jeterson"

// Here is an example with error:
var obj2 = { 
  user: {
    nameeeee: 'jeterson'
  },
  title: 'I am a test'
}
console.log(obj_tree_key(obj2, 'user.name'));
```

**Old answer**: Use a `for` to loop through the `keys` and reduce the oject:

```js
// My function
function obj_tree_key(obj, tree_key) {
  var result = obj;
  var keys = tree_key.split('.');
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    result = result[keys[i]] || 'Not found'; // Error handling
  }
  return result;
}

var obj1 = {
  user: {
    name: 'jeterson'
  },
  title: 'I am a test'
}
console.log(obj_tree_key(obj1, 'user.name')); // Outputs "jeterson"

// Here is an example with error:
var obj2 = { 
  user: {
    nameeeee: 'jeterson'
  },
  title: 'I am a test'
}
console.log(obj_tree_key(obj2, 'user.name'));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you forgot `obj['user'].name`:D

Comment: Thanks @Pilan, I'm adding it. :p

Answer (score 4):

You can access it with:

```
obj['user']['name']
```

Or alternatively:

```
obj.user.name
```

If you want to get from a key like "user.name" to the value, you woulr have to do some logic yourself. You could hack something together like this:

```js
let obj = {
  user: {
    name: 'jeterson'
  },
  title: 'I am a test'
}

let key = 'user.name';
let keys = key.split('.');

let res = obj;
while (keys.length > 0 && res) {
  let k = keys.shift();
  res = res[k];
}
console.log(res) // "jeterson"
```

When the keys do not match, res holds `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, but how could you go from `"user.name"` to `["user"]["name"]`

Comment: I added some simple logic for that problem. Please, see above.

Answer (score 2):

first get the user, then the name:

```
obj['user']['name']
```

or

```
obj.user.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use
`obj.user.name`

Answer (score 2):

You could access it using

```
console.log(obj.user.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 way:

```
obj['user']['name']
```

or

```
obj.user.name
```